# Is the usage of "are" correct when referring to a team/group/band?

Tags: grammatical-number

> **Possible Duplicate:** 
>   [Is staff plural?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3288/is-staff-plural)

It always sounds wrong to me when people refer to a proper team, group, band, etc. in plural form, e.g.:

> Nirvana are the creators of grunge.
>   The Avalanche are on the road to the Stanley Cup this year.

To me, this sounds correct:

> Nirvana is the creator of grunge.

If the name is plural, it sounds correct:

> The Foo Fighters are on tour this year.

What is the rule for this? I seem to be hearing this more and more these days.

Comment: /agree.. "Nirvana are the creators..." sounds as bad as "The data are invalid..." to me.

Comment: I think that this is a duplicate of [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1338/is-a-company-always-plural-or-are-small-companies-singular) rather than [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3288/is-staff-plural).