# Is a music band a singular or a collective entity, grammatically speaking?

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement, collective-nouns

> **Duplicate:**
> [Is the usage of “are” correct when referring to a team/group/band?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4501/is-the-usage-of-are-correct-when-referring-to-a-team-group-band)

What is correct to say?

> Korn* is a great band

OR

> Korn* are a great band.

(* You can replace your favourite band's name here)

Of course everybody there is no doubt about the following sentences:

> The Beatles **are** a great band
>
> Led Zeppelin **is** a great band

But with certain kinds of names, the situation becomes difficult.

> Metallica are a great band

OR

> Metallica is a great band

Is there any consensus on this matter?

Comment: It is never correct to say either 'Korn are a great band' _or_ 'Korn is a great band', certainly not in the same breath as The Beatles or Led Zeppelin. ;)

Comment: ...and a possible duplicate of [Is the usage of “are” correct when referring to a team/group/band?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4501/), which is itself a dupe of [Is staff plural?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3288/)

Comment: Damn! Why don't these things show up in the Previous questions while I am typing out my question?

Answer (score 4):

I think that in British English, *The Korn are a great band* is correct, while in American English, *The Korn is a great band*.

Again, I'm not sure, but Korn being made of a number of people, the plural might work.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can tell, band names are typically treated as a plural if the name of the band starts with "the" and is a plural noun or based around a plural noun -- or more generally, if it seems to be referring to its members as a collection of entities -- and a singular otherwise.  So we would have:

- *The Beatles **are** a great band.*
- *Korn **is** a great band.*
- *The Rolling Stones **are** a great band.*
- *Metallica **is** a great band.*
- *Led Zeppelin **is** a great band.*
- *Nine Inch Nails **is** a great band.* (note that the plural noun does not control here)

Comment: This is correct, but only for American English. British English would use *are* for all of these.

Comment: It becomes even more complicated in cases where the name of the band can refer to both a single person or a group of people depending on context. Officially, Trent Reznor is the only member of Nine Inch Nails, but if he's doing a live show there's other people on stage with him. If the conjugation is plural because a band has multiple members, then it should be singular when a band has only one member. For my money, what @chaos suggests sounds best to the ear.

Comment: Why would "Nine Inch Nails" become plural by that rule?

Comment: @skyking: it doesn't?

Comment: I meant why "Nine Inch Nails" would become singular by that rule?

Comment: @skyking: doesn't start with "the", isn't referring to members.