# Should decades (e.g. '70s) be singular or plural

Tags: grammatical-number

Are specific decades singular or plural? Which of the following is grammatically correct?

> The '70s *was* a great period for rock music.

or

> The '70s *were* a great period for rock music.

Please provide references if you have any.

Comment: This has been a popular topic on EL&U. It’s ironic that you mention rock music; see [“Led Zeppelin was” vs. “Led Zeppelin were”](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/162608/26083), [Is a band a singular or a collective entity?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/11023/26083), [Is the usage of “are” correct when referring to a band?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/4501/26083), and [“Are” vs. “is” for proper nouns that sound plural (e.g., band names)](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/138238/26083). Also [Are collective nouns plural or singular?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/1338/26083)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My interpretation would be this (including source).

[Rule 8.](http://www.grammarbook.com/grammar/subjectVerbAgree.asp) Use a singular verb with distances, **periods of time**, sums of money, etc., when considered as a unit.

The '70s is a period of time

> Examples: 
>   Three miles **is** too far to walk. 
>   Five years **is** the maximum sentence for that offense. 
>   Ten dollars **is** a high price to pay. **BUT** Ten dollars (i.e., dollar bills) **were** scattered on the floor.

Rule 8: [Blue book of grammar and punctuation](http://www.grammarbook.com/grammar/subjectVerbAgree.asp)

Comment: On the other hand, "Five years is ..." could be rephrased as "The maximum sentence ... is ...", in which case it's easy to see why the verb is singular. One might say "Five years was/were spent in constructing the building." I'd be inclined, myself, to use the plural there - though I have no source to back me up.

Comment: If you find a source to demonstrate your example, please make a reference here as well for the clarity of the answer and simply because it helps make the language that little bit more clear and enjoyable. Thank you for your comment!

Comment: Nice find. Oddly enough, to me it sounds fine to say "three miles are too far to walk", although I agree with the other examples. (This suggests that the rule should probably hold in all cases.)

Answer (score 7):

My intuition is that it can work either way. If you use "were", then you are treating it as a collection of 10 years. If you use "was", then you are treating it as a single decade. This is similar to how [teams and corporations](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3288/is-staff-plural) can be singular or plural depending on how you look at them.

On [ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the%2070s%20were,the%2070s%20was&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,the%2070s%20were;,c0;.t1;,the%2070s%20was;,c0) we can see that both are in use, though the search result is misleading because there are false matches like "The X of the 70s was a good X".
[image]

Comment: The _s_ at the end makes me think that it's plural.

Comment: @Archa Yes, but it's also the name of the decade.

Comment: You told that "were" treats as a "collection of 10 years" and "was" a single decade, but, what's the difference? A single decade is a collection of 10 years. Sorry, I really didn't understand.

Comment: A single decade is a single extent of time that happens to be ten years long. A collection of ten years could be any old group of ten years; if you use _were_ to describe a decade you're thinking of it as a collection of ten years that happen to be consecutive years.

Comment: @GuilhermeOderdenge think of it as:  ten years = one decade. twenty years = two decades.

Comment: @GuilhermeOderdenge "one decade" is a singular thing. "10 years" is plural. Compare "That decade felt really long to me" and "Those 10 years felt really long to me".  The first is singular (uses _that_), the second is plural (uses _those_). You can treat "The 70s" as either _one decade_ or _ten years_.

Comment: The best way to answer questions like this. I've been thinking about 'The 1700s was' vs 'The 1700s were', and find the choice still available. But it has to be 'The 18th Century was'. Proximity trumps notionality here.