# Company names, use of "have" and "has"

Tags: proper-nouns

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are collective nouns always plural, or are certain ones singular?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1338/are-collective-nouns-always-plural-or-are-certain-ones-singular)

Should company names be followed by "has" or "have"? It depends on whether a company is treated as a singular proper-noun:

> Samsung has gotten itself in a lot of trouble recently.

Or plural proper-noun:

> Samsung have stated they don't imitate cooler products.

Are both acceptable?

Comment: @Julien: yes, the tiny exception that is British English.

Comment: Also related: [Is “staff” plural?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3288/is-staff-plural), [Is the usage of “are” correct when referring to a team/group/band?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4501/is-the-usage-of-are-correct-when-referring-to-a-team-group-band)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A company is a *collective* entity.  When referring to a company by name, it is the overall entity that is being referenced. It is treated as a single thing for the purpose of verb (and pronoun) agreement.

While there are other collectives that may, at times be treated as a plural to reflect the multiplicty of the participants in the activity or characteristic, even when a company is a conglomerate of many smaller companies, the name use is singular.

> Time-Warner **collects** revenue from all of **its** subsidiaries.

Comment: This is true in American English. However, in British English, "TimeWarner collect [...] from their [...]" is unobjectionable. See the question this has been closed as a duplicate of.

Comment: @RegDwight AAA - Thanks for the info on the distinction.