# Plural Noun--Its vs Their

Tags: possessives

I am trying to determine which sentence is correct.

A) Storyboards got *their* name from the bulletin boards containing cartoon drawings.

B) Storyboards got *its* name from bulletin boards containing cartoon drawings.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Company names, use of "have" and "has"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/77835/company-names-use-of-have-and-has)

Comment: This is a little more complex than the possible duplicate because of the ambiguity of plural storyboards and singular name.

Answer (score 1):

On its face the correct one would be:

> *Storyboards* got **their** name from the bulletin boards containing cartoon
>   drawings.

If *storyboards* are considered as a singular tool in the movie industry, you might **get away** with:

> *Storyboards* got **its** name from bulletin boards containing cartoon
>   drawings.

but it would sound awkward. You would never be wrong with:

> Storyboards got **their** name from the bulletin boards containing cartoon
>   drawings.

There is more than one cartoon "board" in *storyboards*, so you want the plural pronoun their to refer to them.

The singular *name* is correctly distributed across on organization of related entities:

> The Nights of Columbus got **their** **name** from the famous mariner
>   Christopher Columbus.