# "IS" or 'ARE' ? in this sentence

Tags: grammar

Please have a look at this sentence.

"Troy University International Partners **is** not accredited by SACS Commission on Colleges and the accreditation of Troy University does not extend to or include partner institutions or their students. "

"IS" or 'ARE' ?

I think ARE is correct because it is  "Partners" , or partner.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Company names, use of "have" and "has".](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/77835/company-names-use-of-have-and-has) Itself closed as a duplicate of [Are collective nouns always plural, or are certain ones singular?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1338/are-collective-nouns-always-plural-or-are-certain-ones-singular) The actual word ***partners*** isn't really relevant in OP's specific example - it's ***an*** organisation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are valid depending on how you classify the entity. If considered as a homologous, all enveloping group that contains all its constituents or is used in such a manner for being considered as a whole, then it can be classed as a singular entity, therefore "is" can be used.

On the other hand if it is more of an umbrella term encompassing members, which are disparate in location, functions etcetera, then the plural "are" can be used.

I was going to assume that the term partners is irrelevant like FumbleFingers commented, however, in this case it seems to refer to actual international partners so "are" is appropriate as my second paragraph points out.