# When is a subject considered plural?

Tags: grammatical-number

I'm unsure when a subject is considered plural, and when not.

Especially here:

> Williams aim to win at the next race.

Here, Williams is a team, and I have always through this is considered plural, but I'm seeing different uses all over the place. What's the rule there?

Comment: Teams and other groups are more likely to be treated as singular in American English and as plural in British. Please see *[Are collective nouns always plural, or are certain ones singular?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1338/)*, *[Is the usage of “are” correct when referring to a team/group/band?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4501)*, *[Is “staff” plural?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3288)*, and others.

Comment: 'All over the place' rather disqualifies 'there'. Seriously, this tends to be a regional choice, though no one selection can reasonably be labelled 'ungrammatical'. Some people use 'surface agreement' (the team **is**), while some use notional agreement (the team are all agreed that they have to win the next race = the members of the team are all agreed that they have to win the next race BUT the Blue Bull team was founded in 1987).

Comment: @choster: The second part of your statement is false. Teams are more likely to be afforded either singular or plural concord **depending on context** by many in the UK. Thus 'The team was founded in 1867' but 'The team were arguing amongst themselves': is the team (etc) being regarded as a complex unity, or is the term being used as a deleted form of 'the team members'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth True enough; I was trying too hard to keep the character count down.

Comment: @choster: I sympathise. I could often do with say 200 more. (I don't know whether I'd have avoided some downvotes had this been available.)