# Usage of "its" and "their"

Tags: word-choice, grammatical-number, pronouns

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is a company always plural, or are small companies singular?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1338/is-a-company-always-plural-or-are-small-companies-singular)
>   [Is “staff” plural?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3288/is-staff-plural)

When a political candidate gets an endorsement from a newspaper, the sentence would be

> The Los Angeles Times gave Candidate x **its** endorsement.

Is it appropriate to use *their* instead of *its* if we rewrite the sentence to include *editorial board*?

> The editorial board of the Los Angeles Times gave Candidate x **their**
>   endorsement.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is "staff" plural?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3288/is-staff-plural) or perhaps of [Is a company always plural or are small companies singular](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1338/is-a-company-always-plural-or-are-small-companies-singular)

Comment: The second of those two is the best duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

American English uses the singular pronoun, and verbs, for a board (or team, vel sim.) and British uses the plural.

Comment: source, please?

Comment: Americans do sometimes use "their" to refer to "board" or "team"; for example, most Americans would not say "the team put on its uniforms" (at least, I certainly wouldn't). However, for the sentence the OP is asking about, I believe most Americans would use "its".

Comment: And for evidence, [here](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=board+made+their%2Cboard+made+its%2Cboard+gave+their%2Cboard+gave+its&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=5&smoothing=3) is an Ngram showing that in the U.S., "its" has been more popular since around 1880.

Comment: @Kris, dunno. But see the linked-to questions.