# Is "public" plural or singular?

Tags: nouns, grammatical-number, verb-agreement

I wonder if the word "public" is plural or singular. Does anybody know?

Comment: "Public" is a completely straightforward singular noun. What makes you think otherwise?

Comment: @JSBձոգչ You can use "public" with plural concord.

Comment: Related: [Is “staff” plural?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3288/) ◊ [Is a company always plural, or are small companies singular?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1338/) ◊ And many others linked from these.

Comment: It’s all in the context hwww.writing-skills.com/write-public-is-or-public-are

Answer (score 23):

The adjective "public" is neither, since English does not as a rule mark number on adjectives.

The noun "public" is a mass and a collective noun. Unlike "people", it may take either plural or singular concord depending on the dialect and register and preference of the speaker. For example:

> The public are getting restless about the austerity measures.
>
> The public is getting restless about the austerity measures.

...have the same meaning and are both acceptable.

Comment: You'll need evidence here...........