# why is "their" the wrong usage in this sentence?

Tags: grammaticality, singular-they

Why is *their* in the following sentence wrong?

> The modern American family differs in many significant ways from their nineteenth-century counterpart.

Comment: Who said it's wrong?

Comment: Change it to it either "family differs ... from ... its" or "families differ ... from ... their"

Comment: I was going to add an answer, but @prash has already answered it above (+1). As an answer below has said, "family" can be either singular or plural, depending on usage and intended meaning. However, in the example sentence above, the word is being used in both senses (family differs... from their....). Fix the sentence to use one or the other, and you're good to go.

Comment: Well there you go. Two diametrically opposed answers and they're both right.

Comment: In Diana Hacker's 7th edition of Writer Reference there is a pre-grammar test to give students, and every single one of my students got it wrong. I thought it had something to do with family being singular or plural - but was not sure and did not want to give them the wrong direction. Thank you all for your help!

Comment: @Dawn: 'In Diana Hacker's 7th edition of Writer Reference there is a pre-grammar test to give students, and every single one of my students got it wrong.' There is _another possible explanation_ of the data. Grammars often disagree amongst themselves.

Comment: @narx: One has to be careful with one's wording here. 'Collection' is a singular noun but almost always refers to a set of more than one referents. (I've opted for plural concord with 'more than one'.) 'Family' is likewise grammatically a singular noun (ie is formally singular and can take singular agreement) but can be considered as referring to the group as a whole (unitary) or the individual members (usually non-unitary). Grammarians allowing _logical agreement_ would consider '... family is ...' and '... family are ...' necessary in different contexts.

Answer (score 16):

It's wrong because *family* is singular and *their* should be used for plurals (apart from singular their, which can't be the case here).

For singular you use *its*, therefore:

> The modern American family differs in many significant ways from its nineteenth-century counterpart.

Or you make the subject plural, thus having:

> Modern American families differ in many significant ways from their nineteenth-century counterparts.

Comment: "Family" can be treated as a singular noun, or plural implicitly as "the members of the family". Related question: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3288/is-staff-plural

Comment: @tenfour It depends on how rigid about prescriptivist grammar the person judging the sentence is. And, *which* prescriptivist grammar they adhere to.

Comment: Personally, I would drop the definite article in the plural sentence and pluralize counterparts: "Modern American families differ in many significant ways from their nineteenth-century counterparts."  Otherwise, I agree.

Comment: Total nonsense. Singular and Plural are not strictly lexical categories. Plus [singular _they_](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/June05Eye.pdf) as an indefinite pronoun has been in use for centuries in English.

Comment: @tenfour Yes, people sometimes sometimes use a plural with a collective noun when referring to the individual members, more in Britain than the US, but that's not applicable here. This sentence is almost surely not saying that the individual members of a family are different from members of 19th century families, but that families as a collective whole are different from 19th century families. We're talking about a family as a unit.

Comment: @František: Sorry, but I just reversed my upvote after noticing the final word in your answer. It's an ugly sentence in the first place, but that final singular *"counterpart"* is a definite no-no.

Comment: Even if "family" can be treated as either singular or plural, that does not mean that it can be treated as both at the same time.

Comment: @JohnLawler: The singular *they* is unrelated, because it's used for *people*, not inanimate / abstract entities like 'family'.

Comment: The plural example is wrong. The original sentence talks about the *concept* of 'the modern American family'. The modified example "The modern American families..." can only [refer deictically to a particular group of families previously discussed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deixis).

Comment: @Mechanical snail: It's definitely "singular they" in ["the family keeps their"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22the+family+keeps+their%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1). I'll admit ["the family keeps its"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22the+family+keeps+its%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) is *much* more common, but obviously "the family" is **always** considered singular in those examples, since no-one would get the verb form "wrong".

Comment: Verb agreement isn't quite as simple as many people think it is. Try figuring out [tag questions](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Tags.pdf) like **His whole family is coming, ______?**

Comment: Actually, the plural example would be fine without the initial "the", and a corresponding plural *counterparts*.

Comment: In Google Books, ["the family left their"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22the+family+left+their%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) outnumbers ["the family left its"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22the+family+left+its%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) by about 10:1. Perhaps because *singular "they"* is **very** popular, but more likely ["the family are considered"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22the+family+are+considered%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) **plural** by many people in many contexts.

Answer (score 9):

OP's sentence is wrong for most Americans because they [normally, esp. in recent decades,](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the%20family%20are%20united,the%20family%20is%20united&year_start=1880&year_end=2000&corpus=5&smoothing=3) treat *"the family"* as singular, so they would expect *"**its** counterpart"*, not *"their counterpart"*.

It's wrong for Brits because although it's true we [often](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the%20family%20are%20coming,the%20family%20is%20coming&year_start=1880&year_end=2000&corpus=6&smoothing=3) treat *"the family"* as plural, if we did that in this particular case we'd obviously expect *"The ... family **differ**"*, not *"differs"*.

---

But it's worth pointing out that Brits don't *always* treat these "group nouns" *(family, Parliament, the government, company names, etc.)* as plural. In this specific case I think most of us would use the singular anyway, because the family is referenced as a single entity being compared to another single entity (its "collective" counterpart).

It's also worth pointing out that I doubt many native speakers would be happy with...

> ?*The family took its places at the table.

...which just goes to show that there's no single "logical" approach anyway. I put that example up because you can fix it using [singular "they"](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/June05Eye.pdf), or simply by saying "the family" is plural anyway (in which case you can legitimately use "plural 'they'"). But if you insist "the family" is singular, *and* you don't endorse "singular 'they'", you're stuck with the very ungainly form above!

Comment: Interesting. Plural use of group nouns is hardly restricted to British English. That last example ("The family took their places") is a case where it's quite natural in AmE.

Comment: @Mechanical snail: Yeah, but I suspect these (admittedly few) instances of ["the family took its place"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22the+family+took+its+place%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) are more US than UK.

Answer (score 3):

It's not wrong, but I would have worded it like so:

> The modern American family differs ... from its nineteenth-century counterpart.

Here everything is singular:  family / differs / its / counterpart.

If you substitute the [singular they](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_they) in that sentence, it's equally valid and becomes what you had originally written:

> The modern American family differs ... from their nineteenth-century counterpart.

Another way to word it is to make everything plural:

> Modern American families differ ... from their nineteenth-century counterparts.

Comment: Singular they is not valid here because "family" is an abstract entity, not a person.

Comment: @Mechanicalsnail - I don't believe that's correct.  Singular they can be used for words of indeterminate number or gender, and abstract entities like "family" and "staff" fall into that category. For a reference, see [here](http://motivatedgrammar.wordpress.com/2009/09/10/singular-they-and-the-many-reasons-why-its-correct/) (scroll down to the part about "My family stops by")

Comment: I disagree, and would take that example as related to the usual "implicit unpacking" of collective entities. If it were truly a singular they, “My family stops by regularly and **it** always brings pizzas” would be equally valid (modulo whether *it* can be used for animates). The source continues, "The key point here is that it’s not the syntactic number, but rather the semantic number that matters.", which supports my interpretation.

Comment: Also, that's really a different usage. In the "brings pizza" example, unpacking makes sense, because it's the members of the family that are physically bringing the pizzas. In the poster's example, it's the family *itself*, as a concept, that differs from its 19th-century counterpart.

Comment: @Mechanicalsnail: "My family stops by and it always brings pizzas" does sound equally valid to my ear, because you could be talking about "family" as the abstract entity.  It sounds like we'll just have to agree to disagree.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, 'their' is also a sign of ownership. From what I further understand, it is part of what you're implying when you say it is THEIR counterpart.

> The modern American family differs in many significant ways from their nineteenth-century counterpart.

If we were to completely take away the middle part, we'd get this...

> The modern American family differs from their nineteenth-century counterpart.

Now, you can use 'its', but while it is still an unresolved issue with ALL of the English language, it is one of those accepted things. Singular 'they' does exist and it CAN BE used here. (My earlier argument, for this case just is another piece of evidence for the pro-singular 'they'.)

I'd further like to say that you have listed the noun, it is not nondescript. You refer to a family as a person or as (a) people. That is another reason why 'their' is correct. 'Family', in this case, is being viewed as people, as in plural. (And this last bit was for everyone who thought the sentence was wrong.)

Case closed.

Comment: I've only ever heard singular *they* used for *animate* referents. It cannot be used here because the original sentence is clearly referring to 'family' as a concept, not to any particular person, nor to the various members of the family.

Comment: @Mechanicalsnail As I had clearly said in my answer, you _don't_ define family as something inanimate. One would think that if something were **NOT** inanimate, that it would then be animate. Thus, what you should have said was 'Concepts can't be animate', and you'd be wrong there too. Family, if used as a concept, is a moving one. Therefore, animate. I'd hate to think of 'family' as "stagnant".

Comment: I don't know why you guys think *singular "they"* is only valid with "inanimate" objects. If ["someone gave their"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22someone+gave+their%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) (life, attention, whatever) to something, would you say that must be incorrect, and that the only valid form is *"someone gave **his**..."*? [Everyone has their](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22Everyone+has+their%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) own opinion about singular "they", but I never heard of this "inanimate" constraint before.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Where did I say that singular 'they' is only valid with inanimate objects? I didn't. Instead, I had said that 'family' is NOT an inanimate object. If anything, you were mistaken.

Comment: @Souta: Perhaps I'm erroneously conflating your position with Mechanical snail's. But I can't see what animate/inanimate has to do with *anything* here, so why mention it in the first place?

Comment: @FumbleFingers I honestly believe that was bad wording, originally, on my end. My apologies. And when Mechanical snail had put in his/her comment, I was moved to debate a rather pointless argument; has since been removed.

Comment: Per @sawa's comment on tchrist's answer, whilst you can make an argument for "family" being *people, plural*, it's irrelevant to OP's example. People my have different opinions about the "plurality" of "family" - but everyone knows the verb form **differs** must indicate a *singular* subject, so it can't be a plural "they" in this case.

Comment: That can easily be fixed by taking out one letter, 's'. Then the problem would be solved and there need not be further debate about 'their'. Whoo, problem solved, yeah?

Answer (score 0):

Using *their* in that sentence is not wrong. It is right for either of two different paths:

1. It is right if you construe *family* to be a plural, as such things frequently are, especially in British English.

   - Have the family from Iowa checked out of their room yet?  They seem to have left their dog behind!
2. It is right if you construct  *their* as here referring to a non-specific or non-sexed singular antecedent.

   - Any member of the family is fully covered as soon as their individual deductible has been met.

Either way, the usage is correct.

Of course, correctness has never stopped people from complaining about things; people will always complain.

Comment: Here's someone who will complain! The original example sounds like a fairly formal use of language, and in such a case _family_ should be treated as singular, so _its_ should be used.

Comment: But if *family* is construed as plural, the verb should likewise be cast in the plural.

Comment: @tchrist - Your suggestion (1) is informal, and could be taken to refer to individual members of a specific family, and your (2) is referring to a person, and should be _his/hers_ (pending some new non-sexed pronoun). The _family_ in the original post refers to the structure, not to individual members.

Comment: @DavidR Um, no: it is not "informal"! There are [plenty of uses of *family* as a plural](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+family+are%2Cthe+family+is&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3) historically and currently alike. Americans always think everything has to be singular, and this is not true.

Comment: I'm not arguing with your #2, but with your #1: if your justification for using *their* is that you construe *family* as a plural, you must say *The family differ*, just as Brits say "Parliament are in recess". If you say here *The family differs*, then it is the use of *they/their* for a "non-specific ... antecedent" which is in play here ("non-sexed" being in that case *hors de concours*).

Comment: Reading your responses makes me realize that this was not a fair pre-test question! To much is open for discussion - or maybe it will provide a good tool for my students to see opposing views.

Comment: @StoneyB: You're misrepresenting British usage there. We ***never*** say [Parliament are in recess](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22Parliament+are+in+recess%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1). 10 of the 11 results in that link are bog-standard things like *"law courts and Parliament are in recess"*. The other one is some misinformed person using that (fictitious) example to make the same claim as you. And [here](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22Parliament+is+in+recess%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) are 3200 examples of *"Parliament **is** in recess"*, which is what we say.

Comment: Explanation for #2 does not work. You're talking about **Any member**, which is singular. OP's statement was quite different.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  I stand corrected, and humbly withdraw the phrase and its attribution. Will you accept the argument if I, citing [Oxford Dictionaries](http://oxforddictionaries.com/words/matching-verbs-to-collective-nouns-american), substitute *– which is acceptable British usage*?

Comment: @StoneyB: I never disputed the substance of your argument. But OP's  example is inherently "awkward" to my British ear. Many Americans seem happy to just say *"family is **always** singular, so there's no issue involved"*. But Brits have more subtle issues to deal with, because we use both singular and plural according to context. In this case, I'd either fix OP's original by changing the verb to **differ**, or more likely completely recast the thing (as per Lynn's suggestions, for example).

Comment: @FumbleFingers  We are then in agreement.

Comment: Even if "family" can be treated as either singular or plural, that does not mean that it can be treated as both at the same time.

Comment: @sawa: Quite so. One person says they don't mind "singular they", while another says he can't abide it. But they're never going to disagree on the correct verb form! They both ***says*** what they say! In short, OP's family *must* be singular, because it has a singular verb form (although as a Brit I'd happily say *because **they have** a singular verb form* :)

Answer (score -1):

It's wrong because *their* is plural and *counterpart*, to which *their* belongs, is singular. That simple.  Whether *family* is singular, plural or both, and whether *they* can be singular if paired with a non-specific referent (both fruitful sources of disagreement, obviously) have no bearing on the case.

Comment: Next you'll be telling us that there's something wrong with "Everybody raise their hand!"

Comment: Wait. 'Their' should agree with its *referent*, not with the NP it heads.

Comment: @Mechanicalsnail; true, but here there would only be a distinction if every modern family had *the same* counterpart.