# Should proper nouns be used as singulars or plurals?

Tags: verb-agreement, proper-nouns, singular-subject-and-verb

My question is about whether proper nouns (used as the subject of a sentence) should be considered as singular or plural. The proper nouns "The United States" and "The Duck Variations" are the name of a country founded in 1776 and the name of a play written by David Mamet in 1972. I believe it is correct to write "The United States was founded in 1776", because "The United States" is a proper noun used as a singular phrase, even though it is a collection of states. Similarly "The Duck Variations" is a play for the theatre, written as a single work consisting of 14 short acts which are always performed together.

My question is, do I write *"The Duck Variations was written in 1972"* or *"The Duck Variations were written in 1972"*? The plural form seems correct, but I cannot find any rule saying which should be used. Also if the plural is correct, what rule distinguishes the usage of the proper nouns "The United States" and "The Duck Variations"?

I have already looked at:

[Can the name of a country be considered a plural noun, as a collective of e.g. its citizens?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/183003/can-the-name-of-a-country-be-considered-a-plural-noun-as-a-collective-of-e-g-i?noredirect=1&lq=1)
which leads on to
[Are collective nouns always plural, or are certain ones singular?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1338/are-collective-nouns-always-plural-or-are-certain-ones-singular)

[Pluralization of proper nouns: regular or irregular?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/81522/pluralization-of-proper-nouns-regular-or-irregular)

[Collective nouns with plural verbs: the 'American practice/s' versus the 'British practice/s'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/252464/collective-nouns-with-plural-verbs-the-american-practice-s-versus-the-britis)

This final article seems the most relevant, although it does not answer my question:

["Are" vs. "is" for proper nouns which sound plural (such as band names)](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/138238/are-vs-is-for-proper-nouns-which-sound-plural-such-as-band-names?rq=1)

Comment: Titles of things considered to be "entities" are usually treated as ***singular*** nouns, but there are exceptions and "grey" areas (for example, in the UK, "the government" or a company name such as "Microsoft" may be singular OR plural, whereas in the US they're both almost always singular).

Comment: I would use the singular for *The Duck Variations* (and it should properly be italicized, which emphasizes that it's a singular title). I realize that Wikipedia is not a formal reference, but it definitely [uses the singular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Duck_Variations) in this specific case.

Comment: How do you feel about *The book ‘The Duck Variations’ was written in 1972.*

Comment: I would use the singular referring to the work or the collection; however, "Most of X's *Variations on a Theme by Y* are playable by the gifted amateur pianist." Without the "Most of," singular or plural works for me, but perhaps the singular is better.

Comment: Based on the comments it seems useful to distinguish "entities". Thus countries, companies and organisations ("The United States", "The United Kingdom", "The World Customs Organisation" etc) are generally treated as singular. Plays and bands are more problematic. Using the singular for "The Duck Variations" looks OK but there are problems with for example "The Rolling Stones", "The Beatles" etc. Surely it should be "The Rolling Stones were formed in 1962", "The Beatles were formed in 1960" etc.

Comment: @Ubercoder You've linked to a question about band names. Whether you use *is* or *are* for *The Duck Variations* really depends on whether you're referring to the work as a whole, or the set of individual variations: "*The Duck Variations* is a play of several acts"; "The *Duck Variations* are incomprehensible."

Comment: Both plurailities sound fine to me (as a Brit, which *may* be significant) in something like *The Enigma Variations **was / were** written between October 1898 and February 1899*. My choice would basically come down to whether I was thinking of them *collectively* *(Fish and chips **is** a firm favourite in the UK)* or *individually* *(Fish and meat **are** not for vegans)*.

Comment: I'm more concerned with proper nouns than with collective nouns. If we are talking about the proper noun as a whole, is it correct to write "The Duck Variations *was* written in 1972" but "The Rolling Stones *were* formed in 1962"? (Assuming I am discussing the entire play, the entire band etc).

Comment: I am wondering if the "rule" is this: 1. If the proper noun is an entity (company, country, organisation etc) then treat as a singular. 2. If the proper noun is a group, band, performance then treat as singular or plural depending on the s/p nature of the words of the proper noun. Eg "The Duck Variations were formed in 1972", "The Rolling Stones are a well known band", "Eminem is a well known artist" etc.

Comment: I think this does adequately address your question: ["Are" vs. "is" for proper nouns which sound plural (such as band names)](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/138238/are-vs-is-for-proper-nouns-which-sound-plural-such-as-band-names)

Comment: [Google 4-grams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+Enigma+Variations+were%2Cthe+Enigma+variations+was&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20Enigma%20Variations%20were%3B%2Cc0) show that "the Enigma Variations were" is used, but flatline for "the Enigma Variations was". This probably indicates that proximity agreement usually prevails in this particular case. However, the few relevant hits for either in a Google search probably indicates that the issue is usually sidestepped.

Comment: Yeah, I think the accepted answer on @EdwinAshworth's suggestion hits the nail on the head: "The official rule is: if it acts as a singular unit, it gets a singular congugation; if it acts as a group of individuals viewed individually, it gets a plural congugation. There is no difference between common and proper nouns." Which of course allows for some gray areas. Are the Canterbury Tales a unit or a collection? Aesop's Fables? The book of Proverbs?

Comment: I've found very plausible online examples affording both (a) singular and (b) plural agreement to the plural-form compound proper noun "Enigma Variations", so as a user of notional/'logical' agreement (and in the UK), I'd use whichever seemed the more sensible. 'The _Enigma Variations_ are series of 14 short musical portraits by Edward Elgar' vs 'The _Enigma Variations_ was Elgar's first great success'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth What about the even more famous "Goldberg Variations"? It's funny, I would think of the Enigma as an indivisible unit. Not sure what I think about Goldberg, tbh.

Comment: @Andy Bonner (re your second-to-latest comment) Some don't subscribe fully to notional agreement. But few ("... Red Sox **are** ...") avoid it entirely. // I've not used "_Goldberg Variations_" even in speech for over 50 years.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Well now I'm curious. [Looks like](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Goldberg+Variations+are%2CGoldberg+Variations+is&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2CGoldberg%20Variations%20are%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CGoldberg%20Variations%20is%3B%2Cc0) they, ahem, it?, are/is singular. Most of the time.