# Staff were or staff was

Tags: grammaticality

I am having a hard time determining the correct usage when referring to my staff in a sentence.  It includes multiple employees.

Should I say"

Staff were busy this fall or

Staff was busy this fall....

HELP!

Comment: [Exact duplicate](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/3288).

Answer (score 0):

In British English, it's not uncommon for *staff* to be followed by a plural verb. So, "our staff were busy".

**In American English, "our staff was busy" is correct.**

Comment: ...and this is American English because the OP talks about Fall rather than Autumn.

Comment: I assume you're right. Incidentally, you guys never ever use *fall*? It is exclusively American?

Comment: Please don’t answer duplicates.

Comment: Didn't know it was a duplicate, kinda new around here.

Comment: Using *fall* for the season is originally a British thing but which per the OED is now rare in literary use there, although still found in some dialects. Like many linguistics castoffs, it was preserved in North America.

Comment: I can't speak for other English-speaking countries but we never use 'fall' in the UK.  EDIT - I wonder what dialects use it? I've never heard it anywhere in Britain.