# The couple when talking about wife and husband. Singular or plural?

Tags: grammatical-number

I saw this phrase [here](https://inference-review.com/article/the-man-who-carried-computer-science-on-his-shoulders)

> The couple are survived by three children: Femke, Marcus, and Rutger.

Is this the correct  form?

Comment: What does this have to do with irregular plurals? Do you think the answer would be different if the verb had a regular plural?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does "staff" take a plural verb?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3288/does-staff-take-a-plural-verb) or [Are collective nouns {and in particular companies} always given a plural verb form, or are certain ones treated as singular?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1338/are-collective-nouns-and-in-particular-companies-always-given-a-plural-verb-fo)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of collective nouns differs between US and UK English. In the US, the public is displeased because the government is unresponsive. In the UK, the public *are* displeased because the government *are* unresponsive.

However, [some](https://www.merriam-webster.com/grammar/is-couple-singular-or-plural) think it's even fuzzier that this, and I agree. "The couple is..." doesn't seem wrong, but I'd be likely to say "The couple are..."

Comment: American English *does* allow this sort of agreement, but it's more restricted than in British English.

Comment: I'd say 'The couple was at the time over ten miles apart' is unacceptable in either the US or the UK.