Plural or singular verb: A sampling of methods; a batch of eggs; A dozen flowers
I would like to refer to a bundle of more than one thing being acted on, but don't know whether to use a singular or plural version of to-be before the action verb:

A sampling of methods was/were demonstrated
A batch of eggs was/were cooked (or bought)
A dozen cars were seen (or "processed")

On one hand, the action could refer to the bundle.  On the other hand, it could refer to the things within the bundle.
Help?
P.S.  This is not an answer, but based on the comments thus far, it seems to depend.  And I'm leaning toward the form of to-be that sounds best for the intended meaning.  So it depends on whether the situation (or writer) emphasizes the bundle or the items therein.

In British English we nearly always assign "plurality" on the basis of meaning, so we naturally say The couple are sitting in the corner of the pub (same with a pair, etc.). But at least some Americans in some contexts are more likely to use the syntax.

There is variation in how different people treat these things. • 'A dozen cars was seen' would be considered wrong by almost everyone; 'a dozen' is a numeral equivalent, 12. • 'A sampling of methods' really emphasises the different cases, as 'a number of methods' or 'several methods'. Notional agreement seems totally justified: 'A number / variety / wealth / multitude / sampling/selection ... of methods were shown.' • This sounds rather unnatural either way. I'd tend towards 'was' for 'bought', as with 'a tray of eggs was dropped'. But either way, if not allowed other options, with 'cooked'.

@Lambie: Are you suggesting to drop the phrase "A sampling of"?  Sometimes, it's important, e.g., "A narrow sampling of" methods.  On the other hand, I understand your reasoning for singular for "batch of eggs".  But (unfortunately, there is a "but"), it also applies to the other examples, e.g., different samplings of methods were tried in each effort; several batches of eggs were dropped; many dozens of cars were parked.

Possible duplicate of: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3288/does-staff-take-a-plural-verb, https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1338/are-collective-nouns-and-in-particular-companies-always-given-a-plural-verb-fo (and a bunch of questions marked "duplicate"). This question comes up a lot.

"A sampling of methods" is different to the others because "sampling" is not a collective noun: it's a verbal noun with the object expressed by "of"+"methods". You are talking about an occasion when you sample methods. It's like "choosing of an option", "cooking of rice" or "making of weapons" (all not terribly idiomatic but still grammatical).

@Lambie: I'm sorry, but I don't follow.  Are you referring to reading your full comment?  If so, that's what I did.  That should have been obvious by my last comment.  Maybe I'm just missing something about the intended meaning of your comment.....would you be able to elaborate?

@Stuart F: To me, the Q&A you cited is quite different because my examples refer to both the bundle and the items therein.

I suppose it depends on the context.  Among my peers, it's not odd.  Elaborating on what is meant by demonstrating a sampling of methods would far exceed the scope of this Q&A

@Stuart F Cambridge Dictionary has the definition << sampling [noun; countable]: a small amount, number, or part of something that is tried or tested >> This surely licenses 'a sampling/number of  methods were demonstrated'.  Compare << Just a sprinkling of fans were in the stands at Stadio Olimpico as Lazio ... >> (also << a sprinkling of fans was added to the mix for me last summer >>). These fuzzy pseudo-partitives are often used with synesis.

OP is right that there are different cases here. 'A dozen' equates to a numeral; 'a batch of eggs' and 'a sampling of methods' are in the fuzzy pseudo-partitive - fuzzy quantifier morass. These don't all behave identically; notional agreement can be difficult to decide upon, as can where it shouldn't even be applied ('more than one of these people was injured' is mandatory but illogical, to give an example of where synesis is disallowed).
