# Which is correct, "neither is" or "neither are"?

Tags: grammatical-number, pronouns, verb-agreement, determiners, quantifiers

**Bob:** "Can I set the font color? Can I customize the text?"

**Frank:** "Neither of these options is available. Sorry!"

---

Is "neither is" always correct or should one use "neither are" in some cases and what are the exact rules? [I tried the googles and found a big mess](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=%22neither+are%22+%22neither+is%22) of this-is-why-stackexchange-exists :P

Comment: Related: [“Are either of you free?”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8150/)

Comment: Related: ["Neither Michael nor Albert is correct" or "Neither Michael nor Albert are correct"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1144/neither-michael-nor-albert-is-correct-or-neither-michael-nor-albert-are-correc).

Answer (score 49, accepted):

In formal usage, it should definitely be *is*:

> Neither of these options is available.

This is the traditional rule (iirc, Fowler’s discusses this at length).  However, in colloquial usage, either option is fine, and *are* seems to now be somewhat more common, at least on teh internets.  A commenter [here](http://painintheenglish.com/?p=38) nicely describes the sort of thought process which probably pushes people (usually subconsciously) towards using *are*:

> I wanted to say that “neither of us are cardplayers”, but I know that in that case, I should use “is”. But I also can’t say “neither of us is cardplayers”. So perhaps I should say “neither of us is a cardplayer” which sounds ridiculous to me. Is the conclusion that, in situations like this, one should reconstruct the sentence entirely. So I should really say something like “we aren’t cardplayers”. Fine when you’re writing, but how do you avoid getting into a tangle when talking!!

FWIW, “neither of us is a cardplayer” and “neither of us are cardplayers” both sound absolutely fine to my ear.

---

I don’t have time at the moment, but if someone else is in the mood for some corpus or *n*-gram searching (or can find someone who’s already done the research), it would be very interesting to know the history of this.  Is the current shift to *neither … are* a real phenomenon, or is this just recency illusion?

Comment: I think Fowler's simply wrong here. [Ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=neither+of+them+is%2Cneither+of+them+are&year_start=1730&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=5) shows they were equally common before 1800, and while "is" predominates nowadays, "are" is not at all uncommon.

Comment: @Peter Does it really show equal prevalence before 1800?  Google's ngrams appear to jump all over the place before 1800, regardless of what you search for.  So much noise--try altering the smoothing value.  I wonder whether anything should even be hypothesized without error bars.  Or does it simply mean that there were huge swings in vocabulary usage before big media, in our agrarian past? ;)

Comment: @Mark: [They're fairly close](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=neither+of+them+is%2Cneither+of+them+are&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=20&share=) to equal. The huge swings are because of the small sample size, which I should have compensated for by setting the smoothing value higher.

Comment: "Thersites' body is as good as Ajax',/ When neither are alive." — William Shakespeare, *Cymbeline*: IV, ii. So much for traditional rules and formal usage.

Answer (score 33):

I thought I'd add something to what has already been said in @PLL's answer. Merriam Webster's Dictionary of English Usage, which I like for its descriptive style and useful examples, has this to say about *neither*:

> The reason it is sometimes plural is easy to see when you think about it. *Neither* serves as the negative counterpart of *either*, which is usually singular. But it also serves in the same way for *both*, which is usually plural.

The reason it seems more natural to use the plural verb to negate two choices is that we want to negate *both* choices, and not just one of them. For example, it may seem more natural to say, "Neither of these colours suit me" and "Neither yellow nor orange suits me".

It also says:

> The singular number of *neither* is most likely to be ignored when it is followed by *of* and a plural noun or pronoun, for then both notional agreement and the principle of proximity pull in the direction of a plural verb.

It gives numerous examples of *neither* taking a plural verb:

- Thersite's body is as good as Ajax'/When neither are alive--Shakespeare, *Cymbeline*, 1610
- Neither belong to this Saxon's company--Sir Walter Scott, *Ivanhoe*, 1819
- He had two job offers, but neither were ones he felt he could accept--Diana Diamond, *N.Y. Times*, 1974

In conclusion, it says this:

> The pronoun *neither*, then, is not invariably singular, though it is more often so. When formal agreement obtains, it takes a singular verb. When notional agreement obtains, it takes either a singular or plural verb. These constructions are neither nonstandard or [sic] erroneous. If you are writing something in a highly formal style, you will probably want to use formal agreement throughout. Otherwise, follow your own inclination in choosing singular or plural constructions after *neither*.

Comment: Disjunction in the subject formally takes a verb that agrees in the number with whichever element is closest to the verb. This is just as true with *neither/nor* as it is with *either/or*. “Neither the Russians nor the Americans **were** ready to talk” is perfectly correct, but so is “Neither a British flag nor an American one **flies** above the pole.” The controversial case is disparate numbers where you actually have to check which part falls next to the verb, as in “Neither all the troops nor **one general *is* ready”** versus “Neither one general nor **all the troops *are* ready”.**

Comment: Fun fact: In Spanish, negative nouns (ninguno, etc.) are always singular

Comment: I love that they have "These constructions are neither nonstandard or [sic] erroneous" in their conclusion.

Answer (score 8):

Despite what Fowler said, partitive constructions with *neither* seem to have taken mostly plural agreement until some time in the 1800s, as can be seen with the graphs for [*neither of them*](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=neither%20of%20them%20are,neither%20of%20them%20is&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) and [*neither of us*](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=neither%20of%20us%20are,neither%20of%20us%20is&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3). But it does seems that singular agreement is most common today.

### Neither of them *is/are*

[image: Frequency of "neither of them is" vs "neither of them are"]

### Neither of us *is/are*

[image: Frequency of "neither of us is" vs "neither of us are"]

Comment: You can really judge the usage much better by twiddling with the Ngram knobs. See, for instance [here](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=neither+of+thefe+is%2Cneither+of+thefe+are%2C+neither+of+these+is%2C+neither+of+these+are&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=30) and [here](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=neither+of+them+is%2Cneither+of+them+are&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=30). Until the early 1800s, plural and singular were used roughly equally often.

Answer (score 0):

It's *neither option **is** available* or *neither of these options **is** available*.

Comment: "of these options" doesn't make neither plural. Example: "one of these options is awesome"

Comment: Indeed. Strange to see such an answer from a person with 23.5k in reputation (at the time of commenting). Can you motivate your answer, F'x?

Answer (score -1):

'font color' and 'text' are both singular, so you use 'is'.

If Bob says:

'Can I customise the font color and text?'

Frank could then say:

'Neither of these options are available. Sorry!'

because you've grouped 'font color' and 'text' together to form a plural.

Comment: hm, that makes sense, but I think neither is still singular because it's referring to each of them, not the group. "both" would be plural and refer to font color and text as a group.

Answer (score -4):

A. Neither or "not either" refers to at least two things, so the plural is used in this form:

[Neither of them] are awesome.

WHERE [...] represents more than one since neither can refer to 2 or more people, places, objects, concepts etc. Neither NEVER refers to just one, however, you can force this to be singular:

[Neither one] of them is awesome.

WHERE [...] represents only one indefinite reference of the 2 or more possibilities.

B. Neither can be replaced by at least 2 references to illustrate this via substitution:

[Kathy and Jane] are awesome.
Neither [Kathy nor Jane] are awesome.

Using *is* would be akin to the sentence:
[Kathy and Jane] is awesome (wrong)
[Neither of them] is awesome (also wrong)

So it makes sense to use the plural conjugation of the verb "to be" in these cases.

Some more examples:

- Kathy is awesome.
- Jane is awesome.
- Neither of them are awesome.
- Only Kathy is awesome.
- One of them is awesome.
- Neither one is awesome.
- Neither of them are awesome.
- They are awesome.

Comment: Your wording is rather confusing and the formatting isn't exactly helping. Which option do you recommend now, and why? Is your intent to contradict the answers already posted, or supplement them? It's not clear to me at all.

Comment: That's not right. Your reasoning is flawed. For example you can say *0 of them is awesome*. This is essentially the same as neither.

Comment: 0 of them *are* awesome. Just like you would say none of them are awesome. Another example: None [of these sweaters] are blue.

Comment: Hi RegDwight: To clarify: Neither refers to 2 or more. You can't use neither to refer to one option directly and also it can't be used for no choice arguments (or zero options).

Comment: None of your suggestions is awesome.

Comment: Your suggestions are awesome but they are not correct.