# "I'm not being" or "I'm not been"?

Tags: infinitives, participles, progressive-aspect

> I'm not been able to make up my mind

or

> I'm not being able to make up my mind?

Which one is the correct sentence? Why is it correct and why is the other one incorrect?

Edit 10/09/2012:
What if I'm talking about a present action? Like:
"I'm not been able to make up my mind now, so I'll try to decide it later.

Comment: Neither are correct, at least in my dialect.

Comment: @simchona In my dialect, *neither are* is incorrect. 

Comment: http://www.englishclub.com/grammar/verb-tenses_present-perfect-continuous.htm

Comment: @tchrist: Shakespeare and Sir Walter Scott, among others, let *neither* take a plural verb. In my ELU, [there's a separate question for that](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10304/which-is-correct-neither-is-or-neither-are) and everybody stays on-topic at all times. \\(^_^)/

Answer (score 8):

Neither is correct.  Acceptable alternatives include:

> - I've not been able to make up my mind.
> - I'm not able to make up my mind.

If you expand *I'm* to *I am*, the wrongness of your examples becomes clearer.

Comment: I would just add a cautionary note that expanding contractions to check whether their usage is correct is not a general rule of English. It just happens to work in many cases, including this one. (For example, it doesn't work with, "He's not as happy as I'm.")

Comment: @David- *He is not as happy as I am*, is there something wrong with this? I don't think so.

Comment: @Noah: Exactly. There's no rule in English that you can expand the contraction to see how a contraction is misused. That sentence misuses a contraction (contracting a stranded clitic to a weak form is impermissible in English). But if you expand the contraction, rather than making the wrongness clearer, it goes away.

Answer (score 5):

As other people have written before me, neither example is correct and the most likely change to the sentences you provide is: *"I **have** not been able to make up my mind."*

The second sentence is incorrect because of the verb you have chosen  (*to be able*) which cannot be used in the continuous form. However, the expression ***I am not being*** is a correct form if you need to create a passive sentence in the present continuous tense. For example, you may wish to use it to say ***"I am not being*** waited upon properly. I'll complain to the hotel manager!"  (I don't think you'll have many opportunities to utter such a sentence, but you never know...)

Comment: In your example it would be better to say 'I'll complain to the hotel manager!' Using 'with' implies that he is complaining too.

Comment: @TonyBalmforth. You're absolutely right! When I wrote it was 2 am my time and I was sleepy, so I was misled by the different usage of prepositions between Italian and English.

Answer (score 1):

Neither is correct. ***I have not been able to make up my mind*** or ***I've not been able to make up my mind*** are the two alternatives.

Answer (score -2):

been: is used after have/has and had but being: is used with to be.

i.e. I have been working with XY company for a long time.