# Should the following sentence use the English or plural form of the verb?

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement, negative-polarity-items

Is it grammatically correct to use the singular?

> Neither sympathy nor empathy is relevant to the decision.

Or should I be using the plural form?

> Neither sympathy nor empathy are relevant to the decision.

Comment: The first is correct usage.

Comment: Which is correct, “neither is” or “neither are”?http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10304/which-is-correct-neither-is-or-neither-are

Comment: Both are correct, so it is a free choice. In your first example, the whole coordination has the same number as each coordinate, i.e. singular. In your second example, the plural verb matches the conceptualisation _Both sympathy and empathy are not relevant to the decision_.