# Neither of us "Work" or "Works" which one is correct?

Tags: neither-nor

Which one is correct?
Neither of us work there
Or
Neither of us workS there

Comment: Did you try entering them both in Google Ngram? They're both used about the same amount now, but "works" was more common 20-30 years ago.

Comment: If you left out "of us", which form of the verb would you use?

Comment: Related: [Why is neither singular, but none plural?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/537086/why-is-neither-singular-but-none-plural)