# Either of two [subject]s was/were?

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement

Is it correct to use "were" or "was" in the following?

> whenever either of two somethings [were/was] applied [...]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [“Are either of you free?”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8150/are-either-of-you-free).

Comment: @RegDwight: I saw the question you are referring to, but couldn't really conclude with regards to this question from that.

Comment: The accepted answer for that question applies also in this case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

it's contentious, but I would lean towards "was", since it is acting up the individual "either".

Comment: Thanks, that was my gut feeling too, but I would love to hear from others as well.

Answer (score 2):

It should be "either of [...] was," in the same way it is "they have a mortgage that will be repaid if either of them dies."

The meaning of *either* is "one or the other of two people or things." It is then referring to a single person/thing, and the verb should be singular.

Comment: The verb should be singular to agree with the singular alternatives to "either" _in this case_, but nothing says that the alternatives have to be singular.  "Either the Smiths or the Joneses bake the cake," to give a slightly artificial example (because I can't think of a better one right now).

Comment: That is why I didn't say "it must be."

Comment: sorry, I just thought that your answer could be misread as meaning that _either_ always refers to singular things.

Comment: @Rhodri: It's better to precisate than to implicitly say something. I was referring more to the question asked; that is why I given that definition of _either_. In general, I should have said it refers to one or the other of a group of people/things too.

Comment: What if it's in a question format? Either of you is good. Is/are either of you good? Please tell me...