# How do I refer to Congress?

Tags: nouns, proper-nouns

When referring to Congress do I refer to it as a single body or a collective? For example, is it

> Congress is stupid.

or

> Congress are stupid.

Comment: This differs between U.K. English and U.S. English. In England, Parliament are stupid. In the U.S., Congress is stupid. Related question [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1338/is-a-company-always-plural-or-are-small-companies-singular).

Comment: Related: [Is a company always plural, or are small companies singular?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1338/is-a-company-always-plural-or-are-small-companies-singular) The most voted answer gives the answer for collective nouns.

Comment: Mmmm this is more interesting than I thought. So are both right dependent on context?

Comment: I think it's more a question of saying that in some constructions, and in some parts of the world, you can get away with the plural. But if you're not sure, stick with the singular and probably no-one will ever find fault with your usage.

Comment: Also, in the US, isn't it supposed to be '__The__ Congress is stupid'?

Comment: @Peter Shor: I keep seeing this claim made about UK English in this context. In the UK Parliament are *or is* stupid. Both are used, with a slight difference in meaning which I have found it difficult to capture precisely. In general the plural is more common I think, but not exclusive. As it happens I think that "Parliament is" is more likely than "Parliament are", though I'm not sure why.

Comment: Actually, for "parliament" it seems to be more clear cut than I thought. The British National Corpus does not contain one single instance of "parliament are" where "parliament" is the subject of the verb. (There are 49 instances of the phrase, but the subject is always the members/houses/acts etc of parliament.) In contrast, a small number of the 187 instances of "parliament is" actually have "parliament" as the subject. (A rather larger number have "a parliament" or "the XX parliament" as the subject)

Comment: Slightly to my surprise, the same pattern appears for "House of Commons": the BNC has 15 'is' to 0 'are' in the relevant senses. For "government", the BNC has 1501 "government is" to 445 "government are". Both of these clearly include plenty of examples which are not relevant, but a quick scan suggests to me that the singular verb is still several times more common than the plural in that corpus.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are collective nouns always plural, or are certain ones singular?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1338/are-collective-nouns-always-plural-or-are-certain-ones-singular)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In American English, *Congress* is a collective noun. So, you have the Congress, the Senate, the United States of America. For your particular sentence, you would write:

> Congress is ***_*_**.

Depending on where the OP is from, there are different uses in British English (thank you @FumbleFingers)

Comment: There is something of a US/UK divide here (we Brits usually speak of what Microsoft **are** doing, where Americans usually say **is**). But even allowing for that, usage isn't as clear-cut as you imply. Consider [this](http://books.google.com/books?id=yttGOc9RPi8C&pg=PA148&dq=%22congress+are%22&hl=en&ei=F9oxTsvMLI_E8QOZzbmgDg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=8&ved=0CFMQ6AEwBzgK#v=onepage&q=%22congress%20are%22&f=false) usage of **...Congress are to go in a body...**, which certainly sounds fine to my (British) ear.

Comment: @Fumble: I added your comments. I didn't realize that, thank you.

Comment: Ah. I am from Britain. For some reason saying Congress are feels right. While congress is seems more common.

Comment: @Cirtus: With this particular one I think I chop and change according to context. Despite my example superficially suggesting singular ("in a body"), it actually calls to mind that there are many Congressmen involved, which I think is why I'm fine with "are" there. Note - GoogleBooks finds 4600 written occurences of "Congress has voted", against 716 for "Congress have voted", so it's a strong but certainly not overwhelming tendency.

Comment: US usage is definitely "is", not "are".