# Is "group" singular or plural?

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number, collective-nouns

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is a company always plural, or are small companies singular?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1338/is-a-company-always-plural-or-are-small-companies-singular)

When I'm referring to a group *of multiple things*, should it be considered singular or plural for the purposes of applying a verb to it?  For example, which is correct in the examples below?

> A sentence is a group of words that is followed by a period.
>   A sentence is a group of words that are followed by a period.
>
> The group of people constitutes a jury.
>   The group of people constitute a jury.
>
> A group of crows is called a 'murder'.
>   A group of crows are called a 'murder'.

My instinct is that it depends on whether the verb is referncing the group itself or the members of the group directly, but is that right?

Comment: No it isn't a dupe because this question is talking about the usage of things described as a 'group', not just any singular/plural noun.

Comment: The word "groups" is plural.  I think your question is about "group".

Comment: This question is in no way related to the above "duplicate" which refers to the usage of proper names of businesses. This question is about the word "group".

Answer (score 20, accepted):

According to the OALD, *group* can actually serve as either a plural or singular noun. The category they give is "countable + singular or plural verb". So, an example of correct use is:

> A group of us is/are going to the theatre this evening.

For any of your examples, both *is* and *are* can be used. I think the difference between them is as you say: use *is* when you are referring to the group, and use *are* when you are referring to the members of a given group. This [page on when to use "group" as plural](http://public.wsu.edu/~brians/errors/group.html) from Washington State University backs this up, saying:

> When the group is being considered as a whole, it can be treated as a single entity: “the group was ready to go on stage.” But when the individuality of its members is being emphasized, “group” is plural: “the group were in disagreement about where to go for dinner.”

To analyze your given examples, here are some notes:

- A sentence is a group of words that is followed by a period. *Use this form if you're talking about the group itself. That is, a sentence is a group of words followed by a period.*
- A sentence is a group of words that are followed by a period. *This implies that "This. Is. A. Sentence" is a sentence.*
- The group of people constitutes a jury.
- The group of people constitute a jury. *This would be more correct, since you are describing the nature of the group.*
- A group of crows is called a 'murder'. *This would be correct, since you're again describing an entire group.*
- A group of crows are called a 'murder'.

Comment: I agree to some extent, but there are examples where that falls down a bit.  For example, if I'm talking about my soccer team playing another, I might say "Northampton are playing Southampton today."  I would never say "Northampton is playing...", and that would sound a bit like I was referring to the entire town of Northampton instead of the football team.  So although I'm referring to the team playing as a unit, I'm still using the plural of the verb to describe it.

Comment: @Jez--I'm only referring to the use of "group". The source I used only talks about whether *group* is singular or plural.

Comment: @Jez--In terms of sports, you wouldn't be using the word "group" anyway. (And in Am E, you can use "is" for sports teams and still sound okay)

Comment: So, "The Red Sox is playing today" sounds OK in AmE?

Comment: @jez no, but "new York is playing Boston" is, if you know the context of which sport

Comment: It varies with context. But cities can be singular, at least in my experience. I worded my other comment poorly--your example in your first comment using "is" sounded ok. Also, did my explanation help you understand the intended scope of my answer?

Comment: Interesting.  If "New York" were a sports team, it would be unacceptable to use the singular verb in BrE; you'd have to say "New York are playing Boston" for it to sound right.

Comment: @jez sounds like a future ELu discussion. For this question, though, do you get that I didn't mean it to apply to sports teams?

Comment: Yeah. (comments must be at least 15 chars in length)

Comment: What's weird is that all of these examples sound fine to my ear, except this one that's supposed to be correct: "The group were in disagreement ..." That sounds flat out wrong to me.

Comment: But what abt the noun that follows " a group of " , e.g. a group of STUDENT / STUDENTS ? Do I have to use plural noun after "a group of", EVEN it means the group AS A WHOLE (collectively)?

Comment: I would say that for the jury example, ***both*** singular and plural are correct.