# “group have” vs “group has”

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement, collective-nouns

Do you say:

> That group **has** dogs

or

> That group **have** dogs

I'm not too sure which one is right. I'm just confused because I'm not sure whether the word, *group*, is plural or not

Comment: please see: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/39838/is-group-singular-or-plural