# A combination of government initiatives (plural or singular)?

Tags: verbs, grammatical-number, verb-agreement

Does the subject *a combination of government initiatives* take singular or plural agreement?

> A combination of government initiatives **has** resulted in positive changes?

or

> A combination of government initiatives **have** resulted in positive changes?

Which is correct?

Comment: Related: *[Is “group” singular or plural?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/39838)*, *[Which is correct: The rest of the staff is or are? The rest of my family is or are?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/44459)* and the linked duplicates of *[Can you use “team” in plural or singular only?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/266861)*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is "group" singular or plural?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/39838/is-group-singular-or-plural)

Comment: The key question to ask yourself in deciding on a suitable verb here is whether the combination (that is to say, the combining) has resulted in positive changes or whether the initiatives have resulted in positive changes—or if both statements are true, which one is more significant. It's a matter of emphasis, which you convey by your verb choice.

Comment: ...For instance, if you said, "A combination of things has/have helped me succeed," I would be inclined to take the vagueness of _things_ as implying that you weren't focused on a particular combination but were instead emphasizing the multiplicity of the unnamed things. Hence, I would expect the wording to be "A combination of things have helped me succeed." But if you said, "A combination of diligence and sheer luck has/have helped me succeed," I would take the combination, in all its fragility, to be the focus of attention, and as a result I'd tend to see _has_ as the likelier verb choice.

Answer (score 5):

The answers so far are oversimplified, arguably to the point of being plain wrong.

What you are proposing here is called [*notional concord*](http://books.google.de/books?id=2yJusP0vrdgC&lpg=PA53&vq=notional%20agreement&pg=PA666&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false):

> As Quirk et al. 1985 explains it, *notional agreement* (called *notional concord* by Quirk and others) is agreement of a verb with its subject or of a pronoun with its antedecent in accordance with the notion of number rather than with the presence of an overt grammatical marker for that notion. Another way to look at the matter is that of Roberts 1954, who explains that notional agreement is agreement based on meaning rather than form.

The corresponding Wikipedia entry is [*synesis*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synesis):

> **Synesis** [...] is effectively an agreement of words with the sense, instead of the morphosyntactic form. [...] Such use in English grammar is often called **notional agreement** (or **notional concord**), because the agreement is with the notion of what the noun means, rather than the strict grammatical form of the noun (the normative formal agreement). The term **situational agreement** is also found[.]
>
> Notional agreement for collective nouns is very common in British English. It is less customary in American English, but may sometimes be found after phrases of the type "*a* collective noun *of* plural nouns"[.]

That bears repeating. Notional concord is quite common in English:

- *A lot* of people *are*.
- *A handful* of people *are*.
- *A majority* of people *are*.
- *A number* of cars *are*.
- *A variety* of species *are*.
- *A multitude* of elements *are*.
- *A few* folks *are*.
- *A couple* cats *are*.
- *A total* of seven students *are*.

Conversely, you can have things such as "*lots/piles/truckloads* of money *is*".

So, the question is not whether notional agreement is a thing. The question is, whether it is a thing in this particular construction you are looking at, "a combination of [Xs]".

And there is no way at all to answer that question on a theoretical level, without looking at what native speakers actually say and write. Any answer that does not look at the reality of the language is not an answer, but mere opinion.

So, after this long-drawn-out preamble, let us look at the reality of the language, then. Here are the actual usage stats from:

- the [Corpus of Contemporary American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/?c=coca&q=46344218)
- the [British National Corpus](https://www.english-corpora.org/bnc/?c=bnc&q=46344378)
- [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=combination+of+%2A+has%2Ccombination+of+%2A+have&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3)

From these you can clearly see two things:

1. In American English, notional agreement in this particular construction is possible, and common. However, it is less common than singular concord.
2. In British English, notional agreement in this construction is unheard of.

In conclusion, if you want to be on the safe side, use the singular.

Comment: Nice.  I assume that you said "arguably" for politeness.

Comment: @RegDwigнt So opinions can't be answers? I do get your point--I'm generally a descriptivist myself--but is there no room for prescriptivist opinion at all? Many responses on this forum prescribe without providing descriptive evidence. Are you being prescriptive in your descriptivism?

Answer (score 2):

The correct verb form is "has." It refers to "combination," a singular noun, and not "government initiatives."

Comment: This is consistent with the usage found on [ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=combination+of+*+has%2Ccombination+of+*+have&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3)

Answer (score 1):

In the sentence you are shaping, ***this thing*** [singular] ***has*** done a thing (or has had a thing done to it).

***A combination*** of government initiatives **has** resulted in positive changes.

***A tray*** of teacups **has** fallen to the floor.

***A bucketful*** of uranium capsules **has** mysteriously started singing to us.

It would be plural if you wanted to say:

***Several combinations*** of government initiatives **have** resulted in positive changes.

Comment: **A lot** of students **has** a car. **A few** of them even **has** two cars. Got it! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @RegDwigнt: But those are different sentences! This post starts out by saying it is giving advice for the original poster's specific sentence, and then goes on to provides some examples of other sentences with parallel structure. It's true this answer could be improved by mention of tricky sentences that look similar but have different grammar, such as the ones you mention or "Lots of water is running across the floor."

Comment: @RegDwigнt Cheers, Elton. I thought we were doing usage and responding to specifics. All the same, you have a point.  We shouldn't make it seem over-simple, so let's offer, 'A lot of students had a car, until it fell in the sea.'

Comment: @sumelic: right on, *those are different sentences*. Whether *a tray* is singular has nothing whatsoever to do with whether *a combination* is. Exactly right.

Comment: @Captain yes, we are doing usage and responding to specifics. The way we typically go about that is something along the lines of my answer. Check it out. Use it as a template, if you wish. This kind of questions comes up quite often.

Comment: @RegDwigнt Let's not forget the thrust of the actual question. You might well agonise over deciding whether a tray is more or less singular than a combination, but, but... what do _you_ think fell in the sea?

Comment: @CaptainCranium Would you mind explaining your point about a car falling into the sea?