# Is the following sentence grammatically incorrect?

Tags: grammaticality

The team of scientists were excited.

Comment: I assume the question is about the use of the plural verb "were" after the singular noun "team." In that case, you should find the answer here: [Can you use "team" in plural or singular only?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/266861/can-you-use-team-in-plural-or-singular-only) If your question is about something else, please edit it to make it clearer what you want to know.

Comment: Depends on if you'd say "the team are" (which is predominantly British usage) or "the team is" (which is American standard).

Answer (score 0):

It is incorrect, as `"were"` is modifying `"team"`.

In the sentence, `"The team of scientists were excited"`, the subject is `"team"` and the verb is `"were"`. Thus, as the subject is singular the verb must also be singular. With this fixed, the sentence would be: `"The team of scientists was excited"`.

Comment: This is wrong. Please see Hellion's comment above and consider editing your answer. Collective singular nouns may take plural verbs, especially if the members of the collective are acting individually.