# Use of such with the word group

Tags: word-usage

I'm trying to figure out how to use the word "group" with the determiner "such". I have seen it both with and without the article "a" in multiple different publications.

"It would be amazing to be part of such group"
"It would be amazing to be part of such a group of people"

I understand this may be a tricky issue as "group" can be considered a collective noun, thus messing with the whole countable/uncountable issue.

If anyone could enlighten me on this, I'd be most grateful.

Comment: Hello, Pablo. Once I've filtered through attributive usages ('such group activities' etc), I've hit upon the odd legal usage ('stock or debt obligations of domestic members of such group', for instance). I'd consider it non-standard in normal English, though, and legalese is off-topic. But please provide examples from reputable (and '_non-legal'_!) sources.

Comment: The fact that we can "validly" (albeit "awkwardly") say *That group **are** over there, and this group **is** over here* doesn't really affect the fact that if you don't like one of those groups you'd have to include the article in, say, *I don't want to associate with such **a** group!* Note that it's a "zero article with plural" if you don't like *either* group - *I don't want to associate with **such groups***.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Such [noun] (no article):**

This means *the aforementioned* (and is similar to the Spanish *susodicho*).

**Such a/an [noun] (with the indefinite article):**

This means *a group of this type*.

Examples:

- I am writing to you, ma'am, to apply for membership in the Alumni Club, whose Membership Committee you chair.  For some time, I have been following **such group** from afar in the campus newspaper and alumni magazine.  Etc.
- Dear friends, I want to let you know about a new club on campus to promote X.  It is inspired by the work of Clubs Y and Z.  Several longtime members of Y and Z, including myself, have long felt that there is a great deal of interest in the topic of X, and that the format and functioning of Y and Z provide a helpful model for the formation of a new club dedicated to the practice of X.  If you agree that the formation of **such a group** on campus would be a good thing, please sign the linked petition, even if you are not sure of having the time to participated directly, as we must collect N signatures on our petition before the university will allow us to launch the new club.

Comment: This is really helpful, aparente001. In fact, your first option is actually the one I was going after, where "such" is referring to the group presented in a previous statement. Thanks a lot.

Comment: In any case, it seems it is a complex choice of words and not at all a simple one to figure out. Depending on the context the article will or won't need to be there. Thanks everyone for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would say your two statements:

"It would be amazing to be part of such groups" AND "It would be amazing to be part of such a group"

However, that is not because "It would be amazing to be part of such group" is wrong really. It is just unnatural and used less often so it sounds off.

Group can usually be used as a plural or singular noun. This has been detailed better here:[Is “group” singular or plural? [duplicate]](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/39841/356320)