# "The committee has" vs. "the committee have"

Tags: nouns, grammatical-number, verb-agreement

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is a company always plural, or are small companies singular?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1338/is-a-company-always-plural-or-are-small-companies-singular)

I have two statements like this:

> - The committee has approved expenditure of hundred crores.
> - The committee have gone on holiday.

The uses of *has* and *have* in the above statements confuse me.

Can anyone explain me why *has* has been used in the first sentence, why I shouldn't use *have* in the place of *has* in first sentence, and vice versa in the second statement?

Comment: A similar question was already asked here: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1338/is-a-company-always-plural-or-are-small-companies-singular

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In British English, either verb could be used in either sentence (not in US English, where "The committee have" is frowned on in any context). I guess that Indian English aligns with British here, but I don't know.

There is a small difference in meaning, to do with whether the speaker is thinking of the committee as a unit or as a collection of members.

"Have" is more likely than "has" in the "gone on holiday" case, because the separate members will usually have gone to different places from each other; but "has" is still possible, if for example the sentence is in response to a question about why some piece of committee work has not happened.

I would says that "has" and "have" are equally likely in the first case.

Comment: Yep. Just to be clear; "the committee has approved..." because in this case the committee is one unit - an "it" not a "they". "The committee have gone on holiday" because here we're talking about a collection of people - a "they" not an "it".