# Plurality of a group also referenced using we/our/us

Tags: grammatical-number

[This question](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/4094/is-concurrent-first-person-third-person-usage-absolutely-unacceptable) (migrated to *writers.se*) uses an example sentence along the lines of

> ABC is expanding our operations overseas.

As a Brit, I'm quite comfortable with either **ABC is** or **ABC are** in most contexts, but in this particular construction the switch in plurality from **is** to **our** in a single sentence really grates. Curiously, I find I don't have this problem if those two words are in separate sentences.

> ABC is a dynamic company. We are expanding our operations overseas.

Is this just a personal hangup of mine? Or there a US/UK divide on the issue?

I don't think this is a question about whether companies are singular or plural [(as covered here)](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1338/is-a-company-always-plural-or-are-small-companies-singular). I'm asking about attitudes to using both **is** and **our** in the same sentence like this.

Comment: I think I've expressed the same uneasiness myself somewhere.

Comment: Ah yes, here it is: 

'However, for what it’s worth, in your first example the reader might be surprised to find "our" coming so quickly on the heels of "is". In the second, on the other hand, the break provided by the full stop allows a smoother transition.'

Comment: @Barrie: So you did. But you cunningly avoided giving any indication as to whether you personally would count yourself as one of the readers who actually *do* find it surprising. And whether being surprised in this context means "Wow! That's creative writing at it's best!" or "Yuck! Awkward phrasing there!".

Comment: If US standardized tests as issued by ETS are to be an authority on the matter, switching between subject pronouns in this way is a definite no-no. That said, I hate ETS.

Comment: I would so count myself and would be of the Yuck tendency.

Comment: Your question goes to the "plural form" or just plural of a group. A plurality is something less than a majority, yet still the most numerous in the group.  Example: The district has residents of several religions, a plurality (45%) are Christian.

Comment: @Theresa: As the [full (subscription-only) OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/146196?redirectedFrom=plurality#eid) points out, that particular subsense (4) for ***plurality***  is ***originally and chiefly*** a U.S. usage. But obviously I've been aware of that for at least the past 7 years (I don't think I knew it before then).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ABC is expanding our operations overseas.

This is grammatically correct, but doesn’t have the intended meaning. *Our* cannot refer to ABC because they disagree in *person*: ABC is third-person while *our* is first-person. In that sentence, ABC is *transitively* expanding “our operations”.

If we’re treating ABC as singular, then it should be:

> ABC is expanding *its* operations overseas.

Treating ABC as plural:

> ABC is expanding *their* operations overseas.

If the intent was to add emphasis to the fact that the speaker is part of ABC:

> *We at* ABC are expanding *our* operations overseas.

Comment: Perhaps it's a matter of terminology, but I don't exactly get *disagree in* **person**. In the standard American version, "ABC" is third-person *singular*, where "our" is second-person *plural*. A mismatch which disappears for me with the third-person *plural* British alternative "ABC are". So I'd say they disagree in *plurality*. But I'm with you in that if you allow the mismatch, the sentence can only logically be interpreted as meaning that ABC is causing an expansion is *some other organisation* represented by "our".

Comment: @FumbleFingers: *Our* is first-person plural. The disagreement in number is irrelevant due to the disagreement in person. *ABC are expanding our operations* is just as wrong.

Comment: I got it eventually. I don't know why I wrote *"our" is second-person plural* - I meant *first-person plural*. You're saying it's wrong to mix third-person (ABC) and first-person (our) for the same referent, in the same sentence. And that is still the case regardless of plurality, which none of your alternatives do. Okay, I'm convinced. I still don't particularly mind *ABC are expanding our operations*, but I can see now how it's "wrong", even if I personally don't consider this a hanging offense.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Yeah, it’s not that bad. It could easily be misinterpreted is all. I’m a big fan of saying what I mean!

Answer (score 2):

This is a very interesting question.  From my (AmE) perspective, it doesn't seem odd at all, and out of curiosity, I scanned through several of our corporate memos and found numerous examples of just this sort of thing.

On the US side, *ABC are* isn't a viable option for companies or teams like it is in the UK.  However, it's fairly common not to refer to the a company/team/etc. as a 3rd-party entity (when you're a part of that entity). It creates a more distancing feel, and typically you would want everyone to feel that they're a part of the entity, not on the outside looking in.  So to counter that, rather than using *it* or *its*, its common to use *we* or *our*.

I think when you combine these competing forces you end up with examples like yours that sound fine to my ears despite, admittedly, seeming to violate grammatical number (and perhaps even a 1st/3rd person crossover)

Comment: The question is not whether plural or singular is appropriate, you are right, both can be used. It is the capricious switching between them that grates. Pick a horse and ride it.

Comment: @FraserOrr - That's just my point.  The plural can not be used in AmE.  So to be consistent, the only option would be *is/its* or *is/my*. The first option distances the speaker from the company/team and the second option isn't accurate (by seemingly excluding the rest of the company team)

Comment: As a Canadian I have to agree with Dusty. We don't say "ABC are" and we never refer to a corporation or named group in first-person singular, so this is the only combination that works (aside from the third-person singular: "ABC is expanding its operations", which as Dusty stated is impersonal). The original sentence sounds absolutely fine to me and would be completely unremarkable. In fact, I'd go so far as to say that the grammatical number is not incorrect, as "ABC is" refers to the single entity ABC and "we are" refers to the people in the company.

Comment: +1 I agree that the sentence sounds fine to my AmE ear even though I can see the violation. To my mind, the most natural way to eliminate the violation while keeping an AmE feel would be to use "*We at ABC are...*"

Answer (score 1):

It is not a transatlantic thing, it is just a poor grammar thing. Putting them in the same sentence should grate. I think the reason the second sentence is less offensive is that the plural and singular are further apart; the sentence break adding a lot of distance. It is still annoyingly wrong, but the distance means the conflict is less obvious.

Answer (score 0):

One way to sidestep the problem is to avoid the pronoun altogether:

> ABC is expanding operations overseas.

This trick might not work in all cases. That said, I think it still works with "is/our", since it can be read as two different but overlapping subjects, compare with:

> Daddy is planning our vacation overseas.

"Our" speaks for the family, and includes "Daddy".

(As a Canadian, I'm more exposed to American English with singular number for companies, but my personal intuition still leans towards the Brit plural. I've been told *"Apple are introducing..."* sounds wrong, but I still prefer it.)