# Is there a shorter/better term for disagreement in number than singular-plural mismatch?

Tags: grammatical-number, terminology

Consider someone mentioning "a bacteria", where the number of the <strike>pronoun</strike> article doesn't match that of the noun.

I suppose one could say there's disagreement in number, or the <strike>pronoun</strike> article doesn't match the noun but I have always described it as a singular/plural mismatch (or sometimes as a singular-plural mismatch) - which generally gets the idea across.

But it seems to be a slightly clumsy phrase -- and I am often helping people fix their writing (in several contexts), many of whom don't have English as a first language.

It would be handy to have a term that is both shorter and clearer than that three word phrase. Failing that either a shorter or a clearer/simpler term might be useful in some situations.

For example, I'd like to have some other choices for ways to say "Your first sentence has a singular-plural mismatch", either by replacing the last three words or by replacing that term and rephrasing the sentence as a whole.

- Is there a more standard term for this?
- Is there a shorter term? (I don't necessarily seek a single word here)
- Is there a term that while not necessarily shorter might be simpler/plainer (e.g. that might be more readily understood by people who may not have a solid command of English)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase "*a bacteria*" does not contain a pronoun. The problem is the combination of the indefinite article *a* (which can only precede a singular noun) with the plural noun *bacteria*.

The standard term for the matching between elements of a sentence is *agreement* or *concord*. The *Oxford Dictionary of English Grammar* (p19) defines *agreement* as follows:

> A morphosyntactic phenomenon whereby two (or more) elements in a
>   clause or sentence are harmonized in terms of the shape† they
>   take, e.g. with regard to person, number or gender. Also called
>   *concord*.

† *Shape is defined elsewhere in the dictionary as equivalent in written English to spelling. So, bacterium and bacteria have different shapes.*

The lack of agreement in this case a number disagreement between the article and the noun. I'm not aware of a single word or specific term to identify this kind of mistake.

If one of my English learners made such a mistake I would simply say that you cannot put *a* (or the indefinite article) in front of a plural noun. If I were marking up a piece of writing for student self-correction, I would highlight the phrase as: *number agreement error*.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I did indeed mean the indefinite article. That's what I get for posting when I'm tired.

Answer (score 3):

I have often heard "number agreement" to describe the goal of matching the article to the noun.

Answer (score 1):

A standard term is 'subject-verb [dis]agreement'.

Another term would be '{phrase} parity [error]'.  (Agreement is accomplished by adding a plural phoneme to the verb {predicate} when the subject lacks a plural morpheme)

Comment: In the case of your first suggestion: for example, if the original passage has "I see a bacteria" as opposed to one of "I see a bacterium" or "I see some bacteria", the verb (see) is the same in each case. Can you explain how the verb comes into it?

Comment: The verb agrees with the subject, not the object.  Agreement also requires a 3rd person subject and a non-preterite, non-modal verb.

Answer (score 1):

This forum has used the term "plurality" to discuss this issue.  See [Plurality of a group also referenced using we/our/us](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/43904/plurality-of-a-group-also-referenced-using-we-our-us), so perhaps "plurality mismatch" or "plurality disagreement" would be descriptive.

> **plurality**
>
> *grammar:* the state of being plural

--Merriam Webster