# "There are a couple of apples" or "there is a couple of apples"?

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement, collective-nouns, there-is, quantifiers

You have only *one* couple of apples, so it's singular.
There are multiple apples, so it's plural.

Which one is right, "there are a couple of apples" or "there is a couple of apples"? I have seen both used.

In Dutch you would say "there is a couple of apples" because you only have one couple of apples. How about English?

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Couple was" or "couple were" married?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/44013/couple-was-or-couple-were-married)

Comment: I'm glad you mentioned how it worked in Dutch. It just made the question that much more interesting to read, thanks!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There are 3 things that need mentioning here:

**1) *Couple* as a group of two people in a relationship:**

In this case you say:

> Where is the couple that requested the wedding?

But you would also say:

> They are a lovely couple.

**2) *Couple* as *a few*:**

In this case, you use *are*, examples:

> There are a few apples on the table = There are a couple of apples on the table.

**3) As in the 2nd case, but contracted:**

When you contract in *spoken English*, this is the special case where you can contract *are* to *is*, like this:

> There are a couple of apples on the table. => There's a couple of apples on the table.

Because you cannot contract to *there're.*

Comment: Can you always contract *there are* to *there's*?

Comment: @seriousdev: I think it's pretty common in spoken, informal English. For example: "There's some people." Definitely do not do this in written English, especially not formal.

Comment: *There's* is only short for *there is*. The contraction for *there are* is [there're](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=there%27re&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) - where *both* e's are schwas (neutral vowels). It's loose ungrammatical informal speech to say or write *"There is some people"*, and writing it as *there's* makes no difference to that.

Comment: Oh, so me giving evil looks to people who are just “contracting” is unwarranted. I need to silently apologize to all those people.

Answer (score 10):

It would actually be extremely unlikely for a speaker to be thinking of this "couple of apples" as a coherent single unit. In OP's context, it simply means *two - feasibly three, but probably no more*.

Victorian grammarians argued that "a couple" can only be a singular noun. That's pedantic tosh, obviously, but wholesale disregard for this counter-intuitive "rule" has been [a long time coming](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=there%20is%20a%20couple,there%20are%20a%20couple&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3).

[image]

Comment: I wouldn't call the rule counter-intuitive because it works according to that rule in other languages (Dutch, German, Italian). It might be the case it appears counter-intuitive to you because you are used to the multiple-units-thinking status quo in modern English. Thanks for backing your point with data.

Comment: I don't know enough about those other languages to have an opinion. But in English the "intuitive" position is obviously that "a couple" is similar to "a few", "a dozen", etc. Nearly everyone apart from a few prescriptive grammarians thinks like that - because it's a natural fit to the real world, not because they've gotten used to some quirk of English. The language evolves to fit people's thinking, not the other way around.

Comment: Yes - I strongly agree with FF that the (especially British) English usage, 'logical concord', seems to reflect the reality of situations better and thus is well termed 'intuitive'. And language should be a useful tool, not a dictator. Though FF's last statement above flies in the face of the Sapir-Whorf hypothesis (I believe there's a two-way process, mainly **not** language-driven).

Comment: @Edwin: I believe that at the individual level, any given person's "world-view" is probably significantly constrained by the language they have available to conceptualise and talk about things. My metaphoric *language **evolves*** above alluded more to changes taking place over generations/centuries. Originally, a *couple* derived from *to join/connect [two things]*, so the metaphoric extension to just *the two things* initially meant they remained a single unit. That doesn't work with the modern usage, so hidebound logicians/grammarians were eventually overruled by common usage.

Comment: Several parties made psychological claims about whether we think of a couple as single or plural. But I feel that the problem is really one of agreement. If someone thinks of a couple as singular, would he say that a couple nodded its heads and raised its voices? To me that just sounds puzzling. It seems a simpler rule to go plural right off the bat and avoid those strange phrasings. Don't English people sometimes do that with other singular nouns that refer to groups of people?

Comment: @Chaim: "Couples" are always *two people* (an ***item***, in the modern vernacular). Personally, I'd normally say *There's a couple of beers in the fridge* - but that's probably mainly because it's a pretty informal thing to say in any case, and ***There're** a couple...* is a bit more awkward for me to get my tongue around. In a more formal context I'd far more likely say ***There are** a couple of points I'd like to raise.* But I think historically AmE is different because learning/using "standard" grammar has more implications for "social standing" stateside.

Comment: (But I'm also fine with *There's three beers in the fridge*, so any attempt to constrain *me* with "rules" might be doomed to failure! :)

Comment: So... are you agreeing with me? I think that you're agreeing with me that (contrary to all posted answers) the issue is stylistic and says little about whether we think of a couple as singular or plural; but as a matter of style you sometimes prefer the singular.

Comment: @Chaim: I agree with you *for the general case* that to some extent it's a matter of style, but there's no such "leeway" in OP's specific context. Actually, my NGram is potentially misleading, since it matches "credible" usages such as *In the corner of the cafe there is a couple sharing a milkshake*. If I append the word ***of*** to the search strings, there are less than a dozen instances of singular verb in the entire Google Books corpus (as against tens if not *hundreds* of thousands of instances of the plural). That's not really a "choice" - just a handful of writers with strange ideas.

Comment: @FumbleFingers It could be a question of style on which there is near unanimity. Almost everyone out there might prefer the sound of the plural treatment for the reason that I gave ("The couple cast its votes" sounds weird) without revealing anything about whether they think of a couple as singular or plural in OP's specific case (which was about apples). I answer the phone every time it rings, but I still think I have a choice. ALL of the answers talk about whether we think of a couple as one or two, but I doubt that's really the issue.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I avoid "his or her" for the same reason that I avoid "the couple is." The alternatives I avoid have some logic on their side, but they are distracting or confusing. "Someone left his or her coat in my car. If you find out who he or she is please tell him or her that he or she can get it from my office..." Likewise "The congregation rose from its seats and returned its prayer books to the bookshelf" just sounds weird to me. "It"?

Answer (score 7):

The choice depends on how you regard the apples. *There are* emphasises the fact that there are two separate apples on the table. *There is*, or more frequently, as Rimmer says, *there’s*, emphasises the collection, even though it’s a collection of just two (or perhaps two or three, given the imprecise nature of *couple*).

Answer (score 0):

A good thumb: is the "couple" a *single unit* of apples? Or is it a *number* of apples? Generally, "a couple" [as in "a few"] represents a number.

Here, when you say "there are a couple of apples," you are really saying:

> There are two apples

Hence the plural "are" is correct. However, consider the following:

> A pair of aces is the best hand in Texas Hold'em.

To reiterate: **the decision is based on whether the subject of the sentence is a singular or plural noun. It does NOT matter whether the noun refers to one or many things.** A couple [of items] is a plural noun. A pair is a singular noun. Unfortunately, as far as I can tell this needs to be memorized case-by-case.

> My pants **are** blue
>
> My pair of pants **is** blue
>
> The newborn twins **are** happy
>
> The kids **are** happy
>
> The parents **are** happy
>
> The whole family **is** happy
>
> The married couple **is** happy

A pair, a family, and a married couple are all single objects. "Twins" refers to a group of people.

> The twins **are** happy
>
> The Republicans **are** happy
>
> The human race **is** happy (The human race is not a group of people, it's rather a single race, as opposed to the Martian race or the Dolphin species.)

Again, all that matters is "what term is the subject of the current sentence?", no matter what the term refers to.

> That married couple? I hope they **are** happy. ("They" is the subject of the second sentence, which is a plural noun.)
>
> The twins **are** very troublesome.
>
> The twins? That pair **is** very troublesome. ("That pair" is a singular noun.)
>
> The twins **are** a troublesome pair. ("The twins" is the subject - it doesn't matter that the subject describes a single pair.)