# Is the word "management" singular or plural?

Tags: word-choice, nouns, grammatical-number, management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is a company always plural, or are small companies singular?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1338/is-a-company-always-plural-or-are-small-companies-singular)

Which one of the following is correct?

> Management gets its ideas from its employees.
>   Management gets their ideas from their employees.

Comment: Hint: you use "gets" (not "get") in both your examples.

Answer (score 4):

In American English, *the management* is used as a singular [collective noun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collective_noun) (like *group*) as American corpus and Ngram searches repeatedly confirm.  A singular verb in order to maintain subject-verb agreement:

> The management gets its ideas from its employees.

However, it is noteworthy that the [COED](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/management?view=uk) allows for the word to be regarded as plural:

> [treated as singular or plural] the people managing a company or organization, regarded collectively:
>   *management were extremely cooperative*

Also, the British National Corpus comes up with 9 results when searched for *the management are*, 8 of which are applicable to this scenario.  I tend to believe, then, that the difference is mainly between British English and American English; that though *management* is more generally considered singular in both areas, British English is more likely to support a plural interpretation than American English.

Comment: In case it helps, COCA shows 27 to 0 for *is* vs. *are*, and BNC shows 15 to 8.

Comment: Does this answer the question? It says you should use the verb "gets", but I don't see that it addresses the question of the pronoun "their".

Answer (score 2):

Management is planning to hire more workers. = (Brit) (The) Management are planning to hire more workers.

Source: [Merriam-Webster](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/search/management)

Answer (score 1):

BrEng seems to be more accommodating of notional agreement than AmEng. Speakers of BrEng are quite happy to follow nouns like *management, government, committee* and several more with a plural verb, particularly when they wish to emphasise the discrete nature of the members of the group rather than their homogeneity.

Comment: The first time I realized this was on the back of a Queen CD that read, "Queen are ...".

Answer (score 0):

The NOAD reports that *management*, when used to mean "the people in charge of running a company or organization, regarded collectively," is treated as singular or plural.

Looking at the *Corpus of Contemporary American English*, I can find 931 sentences containing *management is*, and 180 sentences containing *management are*; in the *British National Corpus* there are 428 sentences containing *management is*, and 120 sentences containing *management are*. To make a comparison, in the *Corpus of Historical American English*, the sentences are respectively 405 and 101.

Comment: If you look at the contexts though, you see that a lot of the sentences look like this: *The relatives of senior **management are** given plum salaries and never show up* and *...environmental health problems that originate from improper solid waste **management are** mainly...*.  These are not pertinent usages.  In fact, when you search for ***the** management are*, you get 2 results, which are as follows: *the union and the **management are***, and *the police and the **management are***.  Whereas *the management is* gets 27 results, all of which are used in contexts such as the OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

In American English, you can simultaneously use the singular verb "gets" and the plural pronoun "their". For example,

> Management gets their yearly bonuses in February.

sounds terrible to my ear with "its".

In the OPs sentence, I would use "its", because in this sentence you are treating the management as a singular entity. However, I wouldn't say using "their" was incorrect.