# Singular they for an organization, company, country

Tags: singular-they

Sometimes I stumble upon singular "they" when referring not to a person, but an organization, such as a company or a country, for instance:

> Company A is doing well: **their** shares doubled in price this year.

or

> Each region of the country speaks **their** own dialect.

Is this usage correct?

Comment: The usage in the "Company A...their" sentence is not what is typically called "singular they". The term "singular they" refers to the use of "they" for a single human being (typically non-specific or unknown, but sometimes definite in more marginal usages); e.g. "Someone left their eraser on the table." A company is not a single human being. Company names can be used as "collective nouns" which can trigger plural agreement on pronouns, or on both pronouns and verbs, especially in British English. See [Is the word “management” singular or plural?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/46609)

Comment: As sumelic notes, this is not a case of *singular they* as that label is usually applied. Rather, it is an example of *[notional concord](http://www.ucl.ac.uk/internet-grammar/function/notion.htm)*. See e.g. *[Are collective nouns always plural](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/1338)*, *[“There are no shortage of applications”](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/290856*), *[Which is correct, “neither is” or “neither are”](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/10304)*, *[“There Is”/“There are” depends on plurality of the first list element or not?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/140854)*

Comment: Notional concord is fine with your first example (though some may prefer 'Company A is doing well: its shares doubled in price this year'). But With 'region', I'm not happy that it's idiomatic (even in the UK) to have 'Each region speak/s their own dialect'. 'The jury/team/class were arguing among themselves', but not 'The region were arguing among themselves / different from other Elbonians'.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comments, they clarified the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments above, I conclude that the issue in question is *notional concord*, and the examples similar to what I gave may or may not be considered correct, based on preference and differences between British and American English.

Comment: Yep, this is an area that varies between the US and the UK.  Especially strange to my American ear are British discussion of sports scores.

Comment: @HotLicks Sports teams don't bother me so much, though [in the same article](https://www.sbnation.com/2017/11/13/16643020/utah-jazz-rudy-gobert-injury-analysis) about the Utah Jazz, an author will say *the Jazz are* but *Utah is*. Companies are another matter. *Amazon are settling in to their new home in Cambridge*, for instance, I find distracting, even before we get to the question of whether one settles in *to* or *at* a new home.