# How do I ask someone if their name represents a singular entity or a collective entity?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, grammatical-number

In a website I am programming I present the user with the option to name their website site, which can be a singular entity "Mel Tormé" which would present the menu options "About me", "Contact me" or a collective entity like "The Velvet Fog" which would [logically](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1338/is-a-company-always-plural-or-are-small-companies-singular) change the menu to "About us", "Contact us".  I would like to give the user the option to choose "collective or singular" but I'm struggling with how to phrase the question.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can ask the user to choose between *individual* and *group*.

Answer (score 1):

It's a good question.  However, I think that this distinction is quite important, and will most likely affect other parts of the web-site apart from this particular choice of pronoun.

For example, facebook offer "Personal" and "Business" accounts, and they offer quite different features.