# Singular or plural verb after collective noun initialism

Tags: grammatical-number, collective-nouns, initialisms

Are companies/groups of people considered plural? What about their initialisms?

I'm unsure if I should use `have` (plural verb) or `has` (singular) in the following situations:

> The Federal Bureau of Investigation have developed a prototype ...

or

> The Federal Bureau of Investigation has developed a prototype ...

and when using just the initialism:

> The FBI have ...

or

> The FBI has ...

If I'm referring to the FBI as a group of people, then I'd obviously go with `have`, whereas if it's an entity on it's own, then it'd be `has`.

Is there a preferred/recommended use in this case?

Comment: I've found [this Q/A](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/1338/18338), but it doesn't mention initialisms

Comment: I don't think the initialism factor determines anything about appropriateness of tense.  Either way, much discussion here: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1338/are-collective-nouns-always-plural-or-are-certain-ones-singular?rq=1

Comment: I'd suggest the OP read through the cited references and return to decide if he would still like to keep this question. If he has found a satisfactory answer, either this post can be closed as duplicate or the OP can post the answer he has found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recommendation:

> The FBI **have**...

if you're writing/speaking British English, and

> The FBI **has**...

if you're writing/speaking American English.

Yanks don't often think of companies/groups of people as collections of individuals, but Brits much more often do. That's my justification for my recommendation.

And if you're writing a formal paper, don't switch back and forth. Journal editors don't like it when you mix BrE and AmE idioms and spellings. They prefer consistency, if they care at all.

Comment: Cheers - I'm Australian, so I'll go with `have`. You've also solved another problem for me - I now know what BE and AE stand for. (for what BE and AE stand?)

Comment: _what BE and AE stand for_. The other structure is stilted, stuffy, stale, stodgy, and stifling.

Comment: this is something up with which you will not put?

Comment: Strictly, surely, specifically, and 'solutely .

Answer (score 2):

Use with the initialism whatever form of the verb you'd use with the full title.

Comment: That would effectively make this a duplicate question.