# Should I use "has" or "have" to describe what a company [has/have] done

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, grammatical-number, verb-agreement

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are collective nouns always plural, or are certain ones singular?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1338/are-collective-nouns-always-plural-or-are-certain-ones-singular)

I am writing a company profile, and am struggling with the language style. Which of these is better?

> [company name] has developed three technology platforms.

or...

> [company name] have developed three technology platforms.

Are they both grammatically correct?

Comment: You might find the answer here: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1338/are-collective-nouns-always-plural-or-are-certain-ones-singular