# Which of these is correct?

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number

Which of these film introductions demonstrate the correct use of English Grammar? I have used example (1), but have been taken to task for so doing.

> 1. Eagle Films present
> 2. Eagle Films presents

Comment: The company is an entity so it presents

Comment: Both are correct and in current use. Check usage examples from various other brands. You can present those findings in your defense.

Answer (score -1):

In this case, *Eagle Films* is a name of **one** company, and is therefore singular.

> *Eagle Films* presents

However, if the name of the company was *Eagle*, and *films* was a separate noun, you would treat it as a plural (notice the un-capitalized "films"):

> *Eagle* films present stories from around the world

**EDIT:** As mentioned by [Andrew Leach](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/18696/andrew-leach) in the comments, this answer applies to American English; British English tends to take the opposite approach, as seen in the related question [*"Are collective nouns always plural, or are certain ones singular?"*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1338/are-collective-nouns-always-plural-or-are-certain-ones-singular).

Comment: Except that it might not be. See the accepted answer at the duplicate question.

Comment: What do you mean, @AndrewLeach - http://images4.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20121222115453/logopedia/images/f/fc/Miramax_Films_Present.jpg

Comment: @mplungjan The answer is different for American English and British English. In many cases, a British organisation is treated as plural.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Interesting (but if I may be honest, I think it's counter-intuitive); I supplemented the answer with your information.

Comment: Thank you for your input. It would seem there is no 'correct' answer. Usage appears to depend on which side of the pond one is and even then may be variable.