# Should I be using "require" or "requires" in the sentence below?

Tags: word-usage

An established South African survey business specialising in engineering and topographical surveys for infrastructure development & construction projects across Africa ***requires*** a Survey Manager to join their team based in Pretoria.

Comment: Why do you think either is correct?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are collective nouns always plural, or are certain ones singular?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1338/are-collective-nouns-always-plural-or-are-certain-ones-singular)

Answer (score 1):

The sentence you have written is correct.
**requires** would fit it perfectly because in the sentence, you are talking about
 `An established South African survey business` which is clearly singular.

Hope I hepled