# "Boatload of things" - singular or plural?

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement

One of those automated grammar checking tools pointed this out to me.

I have a sentence, "There are a boatload of other options."

The `are` in this sentence gets flagged as not agreeing with the form of `boatload` as singular.

[image]

`boatload` in this usage would seem to be plural, and saying `is a boatload of other options` sounds strange.

Which is the correct usage?

Comment: You can work around this **recommendation** by rewording: *There are boatloads of other options.*

Comment: There are a boatload of [x] is not grammatical. There  ***is*** a boatload of other options. No question. Very simple.

Comment: Well, there we go then. Anyone care to make one of these comments an answer?

Comment: @MikeyT.K. - Not really, it's too trivial. Plus there must be a thousand duplicates but I can't be bothered to go find one. Thankfully Edwin's saved me the effort.

Comment: Answered at ["There are no shortage of applications"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/290856/there-are-no-shortage-of-applications). '' 'Piles (/oodles/truckloads/lots) of money **is** sent abroad each year' (quantifier; number-transparent noun rather than collective noun)" And likewise, 'There **are** a shedload / score of huge crates'. [see discussions at the original]