# Can a collective noun denoting a collection of inanimate objects be treated as plural in British English?

Tags: british-english, verb-agreement, collective-nouns

This grammar page on ‘[Matching verbs to collective nouns](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/grammar/matching-verbs-to-collective-nouns)’ provided by Oxford Dictionaries says:

> Collective nouns are nouns which stand for a group or collection of
>   people or **things**. They include words such as audience, committee,
>   police, crew, family, government, group, and team.
>
> In American English, most collective nouns are treated as singular,
>   with a singular verb:
>
> - √ The whole **family was** at the table.
> - √ The **government is** doing a good job.
> - √ He prefers an **audience** that **arrives** without expectations.
>
> In British English, most collective nouns can be treated as singular
>   or plural:
>
> - The whole **family was** at the table.[singular collective noun; singular
>     verb]
> - The whole **family were** at the table.[plural collective noun; plural
>     verb]
> - The **government is** doing a good job.[singular collective noun; singular
>     verb]
> - The **government are** doing a good job.[plural collective noun; plural
>     verb]
>
> There are a few collective nouns (in both British and American
>   English) that are always used with a plural verb, the most common of
>   which are police and people:
>
> - √ She's happy with the way the **police have** handled the case.
> - X She's happy with the way the **police has** handled the case.
> - √ It's been my experience that **people are** generally forgiving.
> - X It's been my experience that **people is** generally forgiving.

Although Oxford says collective nouns stand for a group or collection of things as well as people, every example word provided by Oxford stands for a group or collection of people only (*audience*, *committee*, *police*, *crew*, *family*, *government*, *group*, and *team*), possibly except for *group*, because there can be a *group* of things as well as a *group* of people.

In general, "things" can include animals as well as inanimate objects. But I don't think that the Oxford grammar editors intended to exclude inanimate objects from the "things". So, I'd like to interpret the "things" as inanimate objects.

Can you treat the collective noun 'group' denoting a collection of inanimate objects as plural in British English as follows?

> *A group **are** located on the mountain's south ridge.* [Assuming that 'a group' here refers to a group of houses.]

Also, are there other collective nouns that denote a collection of inanimate objects that can be treated as plural in British English as shown by Oxford?

Comment: Animals, definitely — *herd, flock, school,* and so forth.

Comment: @PeterShor Thanks. By "things", I mean inanimate objects. Speaking of animals, though, can you treat "herd", "flock", or "school" as plural in British English? For example, can you say in British English, _The herd **graze** in open pastures._? (Not a rhetorical question.)

Comment: @JK2: Yes. [The Sun](https://www.thesun.co.uk/news/3165016/dramatic-moment-wayward-herd-of-elephants-are-rescued-by-crane-lifting-them-to-safety/), a British newspaper, writes *"Out for the count … the herd were tranquillised before the rescue mission began."* Although I think for collective actions (like *stampede* or *graze*) you'd use a singular verb.

Comment: Google has several instances of "_the furniture are_", seemingly from native speakers. For example: _The furniture are classical and elegant but at the same time with a contemporary style_. And _The furniture are finished in natural birch color with two layers of best class water-based Scandinavian lacquers_.  This usage sounds ungrammatical to me, a native British English speaker.

Comment: @Shoe I agree, it's not idiomatic to say "The furniture are...", though it sounds like the sort of thing that **might** have been formally correct at some point.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [American versus British collective nouns with plural verbs](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/252464/american-versus-british-collective-nouns-with-plural-verbs)

Comment: In Google books, you can find quite a few instances of *"the fleet are"* and *"the fleet were"*. Of course, in some sense a fleet is made up of human beings, so maybe this isn't really an example.

Comment: When you refer to "Oxford", what exactly do you mean - the football team, the BMW plant, the city, the university or what?  The Oxford English Dictionary is a highly respected publication. But please don't rely on anything because it has the word "Oxford" in its title.  The word has no protected status as does "Champagne", or "Sherry". An "Oxford Dictionary" or "Oxford guide to English grammar" could just as easily have been published in Yokohama as in the city of dreaming spires.

Comment: Could you please how this id different from 137 Questions that went before?

Failing that could you take it somewhere like English Language Learners, where it will be much better appreciated?

Comment: The word group is not a collective noun, period.

Comment: @Lambie Really? But this site disagrees: https://www.gingersoftware.com/content/grammar-rules/nouns/collective-nouns/ Moreover, if you truly think it's not a collective noun, at least give me a reason why you think it's not. And it should be more than "period". Furthermore, I have an alternative question as well: **are there other collective nouns that denote a collection of inanimate objects that can be treated as plural in British English as shown by Oxford?**

Comment: @JK2 The Ginger site is very iffy. Take a look at its "team".  No English language creds at all and all Israelis, probably.

Comment: @Lambie Please don't shoot the messenger. I can cite many more sites but it just happens that the ginger site is at the top of the search. The Oxford grammar page cited in the OP has clearly said 'group' is a collective noun. Do you even read the OP's question before commenting?

Comment: A subscription/paywall prevents a proper OED reference but, nautical obsolete usage: (1882   G. S. Nares Seamanship (ed. 6) 114 ) comes close to using "are" but is at closer inspection agreeing with ships, not group. If you'll take Cambridge guide to English Usage (I think far better anyway) you'd subscribe to the idea of an implication difference in "are" vs "is" - where "is" gets used to emphasize unity, and yes, group agreement allows either "is" or "are".

Comment: Again, failing oxford source, Cambridge cites numerous other words having flexible agreement, and these also can apply to collections of things. The list is substantial. But for style and clarity I would elide 'group' anyway. Why make readers trip over a word when  it's not needed?  "A group are..." could just be (if pre-referenced) "Those/The houses are located on the mountain's south ridge."

Answer (score 1):

The first word that comes to mind is "stuff" (because you specified "inanimate objects").  Although "stuff" is a collection of inanimate objects, the correct way to match verbs to it is by treating it as singular.  Example:  "Her stuff was strewn all over the room."

Another noun that reinforces and confirms this rule is "luggage".  Example:  "Our bright red luggage was easy to spot in the carousel."

Comment: Welcome to english.stackexchange. As with all stack exchange sites this is strictly a Q&A site, not a discussion forum. As such anything posted in the Answer box must answer the Question. The Question in this case being either "*Can a collective noun denoting a collection of inanimate objects be treated as plural in British English?*", or possibly "are there [...] collective nouns that denote a collection of inanimate objects that can be treated as plural in British English [...]?" You don't appear to have answered either directly. You can edit your answer by clicking the "edit" under it.

Answer (score -2):

Grammar Monster [collective nouns](http://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/collective_nouns.htm) gives this list; also consider *group*, which can apply to a *collection* of just about anything (stamps, precious stones).

> A bouquet of flowers
>
> A bunch of flowers
>
> A fleet of ships
>
> A forest of trees
>
> A galaxy of stars
>
> A pack of cards
>
> A pack of lies
>
> A pair of shoes
>
> A range of mountains
>
> A wad of notes

The OP asks, "Can any of the collective nouns in your answer be treated as plural when used alone?

A quick Google Ngram search reveals that only "pair" is sometimes used with a plural verb.

Here is the Google NGram for "pair are". books.google.com/ngrams/… Some of the references are to shoes or socks; many are to anatomical structures. Others are to mathematics. Many are false positives--e.g., "the two lines of its pair are connected" (pair is not the noun governing are". You might find this Q&A interesting also : english.stackexchange.com/questions/7186/… –

Comment: Thanks. But my question specifically asks about "the collective noun as presented by Oxford", not just any collective noun. And the title of the Oxford grammar page is "Matching verbs to collective nouns", which they find problematic because they can be treated as plural even when they're in the singular at least in British English, and because some of them (e.g., _police_) can be treated as plural even in American English. So, can any of the collective nouns in your answer be treated as plural when used alone? _The bouquet are beautiful_ (?)

Comment: In those search results with "pair", does "pair" mean a pair of inanimate objects when they're treated as plural? If so, could you show me some of those search results?

Comment: This is just a list of collective nouns of inanimate objects; it doesn't say whether plural or singular verb agreement should be (/can be) used.

Comment: @AndyT No, it doesn't.  Instead of sniping and downvoting, why don't you provide an answer? Make a list of collective nouns of inanimate objects, determine appropriate verbs in American and British English, explain circumstances (rule, common usage, whatever) and post.

Comment: Actually the comment answers this; pair is a collective often used with a plural verb.  It may be the only one.  Find another.

Comment: @Xanne - So, you admit what you've written doesn't answer the question, and yet you're complaining that I've downvoted? As far as writing my own answer - when I visited this question I upvoted another answer which I thought was good and answered the OP's question. The owner of that answer has since deleted it, but hey.

Comment: The links are not links.

Comment: You can always copy and paste them into the url box.