# How to conjugate the verb after an appositive?

Tags: grammar

I have the following sentence

> I believe you, someone called trustworthy, is not lying.

Should it be 'is not lying' or 'are not lying'?

Basically, do you conjugate the verb based off the appositive or what it's explaining?

Also does whether the appositive precedes or follows what it's explaining affect the conjugation?
Example:

> A collection of plants, the rainforest is green.

Should it be 'is green' or 'are green'?

Comment: You got yourself an ambiguous sentence that is off as it is. "I believe you, someone called trustworthy is not lying" means trustworthy Pat is not lying. "I believe you, someone called trustworthy, **are** not lying" means that you are called trusty and would not lie.

Comment: The "rainforest" example depends on singular vs plural, which isn't so clear-cut. "A collection" would seem on the surface to be singular, but [it's](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/421497/can-a-collective-noun-denoting-a-collection-of-inanimate-objects-be-treated-as-p) [not](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1338/are-collective-nouns-always-plural-or-are-certain-ones-singular) [always](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/112316/plural-or-singular-verb-for-collective-term) so simple. But, to adapt the 1st example: "A trustworthy person, you are not lying."

Comment: Both sentences are more than awkward and neither provides a reasonable example. The appositive is offset by commas and is basically adjectival to the main subject: it does not affect the verb. *"The forests, the pride of our nation, **are** burning."* -> *"The pride of our nation, the forests, **is** burning."*

Comment: A supplementary (non-defining) appositive has no bearing on the form of the verb, so the 2 sg form "are" is correct. Re your second question, an appositive never precedes but always follows the NP it modifies or is supplement to. Your example is best written as "The rainforest, a collection of plants is green", but note that "a collection of plants" is not an appositive but simply an ascriptive NP.

Comment: @YosefBaskin Your first example is missing the second comma, which makes "someone called trustworthy" a parenthetical, not the subject of a clause.

Comment: @Barmar I believe the sentence can use either one comma and the construct of "... someone is not lying" or two commas, for apposition, and "You...are not lying."

Comment: @YosefBaskin Right. But the question is clearly about the sentence that uses two commas for apposition. So it's not ambiguous.