# "team of engineers IS standing by" or "team of engineers ARE standing by"?

Tags: grammar, verb-agreement

Which is correct: "Our team of engineers is standing by" or "Our team of engineers are standing by"?

Comment: I think there is already a question about words like _team_ being plural or singular. It depends from the language you are using: American English and British English consider them differently.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: I don't think it has anything to do with AmE or BrE. (Unlike company names, *Parliament/Congress*, etc.) [See this Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=team+of+scientists+was%3Aeng_us_2012%2Cteam+of+scientists+were%3Aeng_gb_2012%2Cteam+of+scientists+was%3Aeng_gb_2012%2Cteam+of+scientists+were%3Aeng_us_2012&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cteam%20of%20scientists%20was%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cteam%20of%20scientists%20was%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cteam%20of%20scientists%20were%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: @PeterShor I was trying to give a summary of what I recall said in that other question.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: I think *team of ...* is one of a class of expressions which can be plural both in British English and American English.

Answer (score 3):

The answer depends on whether your regional English considers "team" a plural noun or a singular noun.

The subject of the sentence is "team", and "of engineers" is just a descriptive addition. So the verb should be the one appropriate for the subject "team": `is` if you consider it singular, and `are` if you consider it plural.

In American English, it is (generally) correct to say "Our team of engineers **is** standing by," since "team" is usually singular.

In British or other types of English, it might be `are`, if "team" is used as a plural.

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/1338

Answer (score 2):

*Is*, since the word *team* is singular.

Comment: The team are not ready yet.