# Does/do any group want to give their presentation?

Tags: grammar, singular-they

1.Does any group want to give their presentation?

The above sentence looks grammatically correct to me. However, I am confused between the use of do and does here. (The presence of "their" and "any group" which is singular). Could anyone suggest me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are collective nouns always plural, or are certain ones singular?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1338/are-collective-nouns-always-plural-or-are-certain-ones-singular)

Comment: 'Their' as opposed to 'its' influences the choice of verb-form here.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth What if "their" is the *singular their*? I don't think the question has an answer other than both are right, but does sound more idiomatic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least in BrE, it really depends on whether you view a "group" as a single unit or you focus on the individual parts of the "group".

"Does any group ... ?" implies that each group gives their pre as a single unit, while "Do any group ... ?" is equal to "Do the people of any group ...?"

However, American English takes a slightly different approach to the agreement of verbs with collective nouns, where there is a very strong preference for the use of singular verbs with such nouns.

See [here](http://www.learnenglish.de/grammar/nouncollective.html) and [here](http://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2011/09/agreement-over-collective-nouns/) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two ways to better handle this in American English, Vinnie:

1. Treat everything as singular - Does any group want to give **a**
   presentation?
2. Be more polite by avoiding "want" - Would any group like to give
   their presentation?

I realize that the second construction could also replace "their" with "a", but the fact that "would" is not conjugated serves to gloss over any disagreement in number.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what’s written in the [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/any), it’s context-dependent: ‘any’ refers to either a single or some amount of whatever is referred to; in other words I would argue one could benefit by treating ‘any’ as an adjective (even though it is a pronoun, determiner or adverb). I’ll allow myself to use the examples given by *OD* (punctuation added):

- We needed more sugar but there wasn’t any left. (singular verb)
- Are any of the new videos available? (plural verb)

In the first case, ‘any’ refers to ‘sugar’, which is singular; hence a singular verb is required. Note that ‘sugar’ is singular, despite the phrasing being ‘more sugar’; this can be read as ‘more *of* sugar’, which reveals that we are dealing with a partitive genitive; with partitive genitives, that which is being referred to is usually singular. In the second case, ‘any’ refers to ‘the new videos’; it is clear then that the verb needs to be in plural.

Referring back to your example sentences—‘Does any group want to give their presentation?’—one could analyse it the same way: From context, it is clear that any is referring to a singular; we could have written it as ‘Does any *one* group want to …’, making it clear that group should be treated as singular. Were the question phrased differently, e.g. ‘… any [of the] groups …’, then ‘any’ would (again, like an adjective) be pointing to the plural ‘groups’, requiring the plural verb: ‘Do any [of the] groups …’.

All the above disregards that one could consider ‘group’ a mass noun, thereby—as has been pointed out by the others—allowing it to take a plural verb. The method for analysing and understanding the syntax still applies, though.

Source for grammar: Eitrem, *Latinsk grammatikk*, 3rd edition (Tosterud & Kraggerud), Aschehoug 2006: §§ 81 and 82.