# A huge crowd were/was

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement, collective-nouns

Should I use "was" or "were" in the following context?

> A huge crowd were/was present there.

Comment: Though those not even mentioning that 'The crowd were by now making their exit' say is acceptable (using notional agreement) are not being even-handed, singular agreement in this example sounds far more natural. '**A** huge crowd' virtually demands singular agreement.

Comment: I'm like 80% sure that this is an example where AmE uses the singular and BrE uses the plural (much like "team" or "group").  Anyway I'm sure about the AmE part.

Comment: @Casey. No. I use notional agreement, and I'd use 'was' here as the composite crowd rather than its individual members is being considered. It's easier to see with 'the team was founded in 1880' but 'the team were fighting among themselves'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I stand corrected.  Both of them sound totally wrong to me so my intuition is not so good.

Comment: @Edwin Your second example above, while I understand its plain meaning easily, just looks poorly constructed to me. Obviously personal taste and usage vary, and a "correct" usage is one that makes its intended meaning clear, but adding *members* after *team* and before *were* produces an obviously superior (clearer) sentence, to my eye, than relying on synesis and a more complex parsing of each word.

Comment: @Upper_Case Not true.  "The cat seems sleeping" is easy to understand but also plainly incorrect.

Comment: @Casey If enough people used such a construction, it would *become* correct, at least in terms of usage. Language *is* how it is *used*, and the rules change over time. I do agree that your example violates the currently-standing rules, but adhering to arbitrary (if sometimes sensible) and changing rules, only for the sake of having followed those rules, seems a poor standard for judging a method of communicating ideas.

Comment: @Upper_Case However it looks to you, notional agreement is considered at least as grammatical as formal agreement. Finding examples of 'the Miami Heat are ...' and 'the Miami Heat is ...' on the internet seems to show that US usage isn't really standardised.

Comment: @Edwin so then the answer, in your opinion, is that either is acceptable and neither is preferred (at least in the U.S.). Why not post that as an answer? I'd upvote it, given your explanations in comments.

Comment: @Upper_Case **No**. I've made this clear in my first comment. (1) I believe notional agreement to have distinct advantages over formal agreement. (2) Most grammarians agree that it's wrong to label either formal agreement or notional agreement as ungrammatical. (3) Notional agreement needs to be decided on in a case-by-case way: is the aggregation or are the individual members really being referenced? (3b) Sometimes this can be hard to judge in individual cases. //// In this particular case, I'd say correct notional agreement and formal agreement  come up with the same answer: choose _was_....

Comment: I'm not saying that the choice of _was_ rather than _were_ is wrong where answerers have stated this; I'm saying that answers stating that this answer follows because formal agreement is the only grammatical option ('_crowd_ is a singular noun') have arrived at the correct answer the wrong way.

Comment: @Upper_Case Without arbitrary rules you don't have a grammar.  Without a grammar you don't have a language.  That's one of the basic principles of linguistics.

Comment: See *[Are collective nouns always plural, or are certain ones singular?](/q/1338)*, *[Is “audience” singular or plural?](/q/58692)*, *[Collective nouns and subject-verb agreement: general rule or arbitrary?](/q/79668)*, *[Does “staff” take a plural verb?](/q/3288)*, and many, many linked questions.

Comment: smells like a duplicate...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are collective nouns always plural, or are certain ones singular?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1338/are-collective-nouns-always-plural-or-are-certain-ones-singular)

Answer (score 3):

**Was** is preferable in this particular example, and in general with the word *crowd.* However, due to the phenomenon of "notional agreement", plural agreement is also possible in principle with the word *crowd,* and may sound acceptable in some circumstances (acceptability judgments for specific examples are likely to differ between speakers).

In general, collective nouns can take either singular agreement, according to their form, or plural agreement, according to their sense. This basic principle is mentioned by the answers to the following question ([Are collective nouns always plural, or are certain ones singular?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1338/are-collective-nouns-always-plural-or-are-certain-ones-singular)) along with some generalizations that may be helpful. (I do think it is good to remember that verb agreement with collective nouns often tends to be different on different sides of the Atlantic, but I think this is often stated as too much of an absolute. I'm an American English speaker, and I feel like the situation is more complicated than "singular agreement in American English, plural agreement in British English"; I've heard the same from British English speakers, and British English guides often say that either singular or plural agreement can be used, sometimes with subtle differences in implied meaning.)

The word *crowd* seems to rarely take plural agreement, even in dialects where notional agreement is common for some other collective nouns. The [Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=crowd%20are%3Aeng_us_2012%2Ccrowd%20is%3Aeng_us_2012%2C%20crowd%20are%3Aeng_gb_2012%2Ccrowd%20is%3Aeng_gb_2012&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccrowd%20are%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccrowd%20is%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccrowd%20are%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccrowd%20is%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0) shows the expected difference between British and American English, but it is relatively small:

[image]

The frequency of "crowd are" may even be an exaggeration of the  frequency of true plural agreement with the word "crowd", since I think this chart picks up false positives like "the individuals in the crowd are...".

So in general, as a writer, you'll be safe if you use singular agreement.

However, you may encounter plural agreement with the word "crowd" in things that you read, and it is not necessarily an error.

Here are links to discussions of this topic on other websites:

- UsingEnglish.com: [The crowd was/were getting.....](https://www.usingenglish.com/forum/threads/231262-The-crowd-was-were-getting)
- WordReference.com: [crowd <have or has> been fighting](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/crowd-have-or-has-been-fighting.3130025/)

Here are some examples I found on Google Books of plural agreement with the word "crowd":

- > "After the deluge," when **"our crowd" are** out of office and scattered, the anti- Washington crowd here will be sure to secure the influence of The Bee.

  Ralph Waldo Tyler to Emmett Jay Scott, Washington D.C., Dec. 11, 1912 in *[Booker T. Washington Papers Volume 12: 1912-14](https://books.google.com/books?id=41PlZmBiySAC&pg=PA87&dq=%22crowd%20are%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjTnre398rVAhVBw2MKHUGsB4I4HhDoAQglMAA#v=onepage&q=%22crowd%20are%22&f=false),* edited by Louis R. Harlan and Raymond W. Smock
- > A crowd of workpeople will be required all at once to pick up the sheaves, or to cart them to the rick; and the difference will lie in this, that while now **the crowd are** employed, say twelve hours, then they will be employed only nine.

  *[Hodge and His Masters](https://books.google.com/books?id=NZ34kvJDSF8C&pg=PA268&dq=%22crowd%20are%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjO9c3Z-MrVAhUDLmMKHdWECJU4KBDoAQhCMAU#v=onepage&q=%22crowd%20are%22&f=false),* by Richard Jefferies (p. 268)
- > This happens everywhere The Cure go, but **the Chicago crowd are** going to be luckier than most—depending on how sociable the band are or aren't feeling after a show, the tour bus is often sent off empty, while Smith and company are spirited away in anonymous, windowless minibuses.

  *[Rock and Hard Places: Travels to Backstages, Frontlines and Assorted Sideshows](https://books.google.com/books?id=USI4AAAAQBAJ&pg=PA79&dq=%22crowd%20are%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjO9c3Z-MrVAhUDLmMKHdWECJU4KBDoAQhNMAc#v=onepage&q=%22crowd%20are%22&f=false),* by Andrew Mueller (p. 79)
- > You are in the area of the world now known as Southern Mexico and Guatemala, and **the roaring crowd are** all Mayan—an Indian people famed for their buildings, astronomy, and ball games.

  *[The Time Travelers' Handbook: A Wild, Wacky, and Wooly Adventure Through History!](https://books.google.com/books?id=Mugj_V7EmK0C&pg=PA5&dq=%22crowd%20are%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjg7LqP-srVAhWpgVQKHY0-AjA4PBDoAQglMAA#v=onepage&q=%22crowd%20are%22&f=false),* by Lottie Stride
- > **The crowd were** more violent than on the previous occasion, and he repeated that they began the attack on the emergency men, and then the police interfered.

  "Tithe Disturbances in North Wales", in *[Hansard's Parliamentary Debates](https://books.google.com/books?id=s4w0AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA1433&lpg=PA1433&dq=%22crowd%20were%22&source=bl&ots=rGXmxc3CyF&sig=cHi2bdCyh7nP7nOiiOUHvJZTeyc&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiijP7Q_MrVAhXIqFQKHV7sA6w4ChDoAQgvMAQ#v=onepage&q=%22crowd%20were%22&f=false),* Third Series, Vol 326, 1888

Since I'm an American English speaker, and I haven't thought about this before, I can't precisely describe when "crowd" can take notional plural agreement. However, I would say based on the above examples that plural agreement is made more likely by the following circumstances:

- a preceding definite article: "the [..] crowd" seems more likely to be treated as plural than "a crowd"
- a following "of [plural noun]", or maybe even just proximity to "a crowd of..." (as in the second example)
- use of a plural pronoun like "them" or "themselves" to refer to the crowd later in the sentence (this factor is mentioned in the linked UsingEnglish and WordReference threads)
- use of the word in the sense that [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/crowd) gives second, as "a group of friends, or a set of people who share the same interests or job [informal]". Collins' example sentence for this definition shows plural agreement:

  > **All the old crowd have** come out for this occasion.

I would say that plural agreement seems fairly infelicitous in your sentence because none of these circumstances apply.

Comment: Just revisiting via a duplicate. Fine answer.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

Discussion in comments have led me to adjust my answer (for posterity; current downvotes are fair and this answer should probably not be the accepted one). Which form is grammatically correct is unclear, to the extent that it may be that neither is correct or incorrect. So no ruling on which is more correct, by any standard, from me.

As for what you should use, in the U.S. *was* is far more common in my region (the Midwest), though neither would be unfamiliar. Someone might attempt to correct you if you use *were*, whether or not that correction is valid, and I have *never* encountered someone correcting from *was*.

---

Original Answer:

**Was**.

Crowd is a singular noun, and so the verb is conjugated accordingly.

Comment: Would you say 'Thirty dollars are too much to pay for a paperback'? Or 'The team was fighting among itself'?

Comment: @Edwin I might, if I wanted to call attention to the specific number of dollars rather than the singular unit of price. I might also say "thirty is too much". The issue appears, to me, to be that the true subject of your example (the price) is unstated, rather than that the rules of grammar flex here. I take your point that common usage is sloppy in these cases, but to the extent that there is a "correct" answer to the question, this is it.

Comment: There have been many cases on ELU where just about everyone has agreed that the 'rule' 'singular nouns must always take singular verb-forms' needs ditching. You'd read 'England was beaten 2-0' in an Australian paper and perhaps in an American one, but _**never**_ in an English one.

Comment: @Edwin The rules are arbitrary, but when they exist they exist. I'm not a big fan of following "grammar rules" just for the sake of having done so, but the only interpretation I can see of your position is that there is no correct conjugation here because differing rules exist at the same time, even if they exist in entirely different contexts (i.e., if all Australians would use single-single, the fact that Brits may not doesn't make the Australian way incorrect, especially not in Australia).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth My ears tell me "England were beaten" would certainly not appear in an American paper.

Comment: @Casey But notional agreement would be covered in a decent grammar, whether written in America or Britain.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Sure.  But in your particular example, it sounds jarringly wrong to my ears.

Comment: @Upper-Case The usual stance by grammarians is that neither formal agreement nor notional agreement should be termed 'ungrammatical'. I'm contesting answers that implicitly do so ('The correct usage would be "a huge crowd was present there." This is because _crowd_ is singular.')  sumelic's answer comes up with 'was is preferable' but does so in an informed way.

Comment: @Casey My ears tell me 'England was beaten 2-0' would certainly not appear in a British newspaper. England still retains some claims on the language. I'm not complaining about the US usage 'England was beaten 2-0'. I'm saying that it's wrong for people to brand unfamiliar-to-them but still familiar-to-millions-of-proficient-Anglophones usages as wrong. I see 'The correct usage would be "a huge crowd was present there." This is because _crowd_ is singular.' has been downvoted.

Comment: @Casey But we westpondians do say things like *[Boston Police are seeking](https://www.bostonglobe.com/metro/2017/08/04/police-seek-suspect-beacon-hill-ring-theft/OAWIEBUleE1TIrLnXKDrkN/story.html)*, and *[the faculty are flabbergasted](http://www.latimes.com/local/california/la-me-lopez-puliafito-nikias-07202017-story.html)*, and indeed *[the Jazz are 2-3](http://www.sltrib.com/sports/2014/11/07/monson-jazz-did-more-than-beat-lebron-they-made-basketball-fun-again/)*, so the notion that westpondians treat all collectives as singular is at minimum a great oversimplification.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I just wanted to follow up on your thing about how Australian and "maybe American" papers would prefer "was," not claim that nobody should use a construction not used in the dialect of English I speak.

Answer (score -2):

The correct usage would be "a huge crowd *was* present there." This is because crowd is singular. Although there are many people in the crowd, there is only one collective body that is the crowd.

Comment: That is how it works in Romance languages (eg Spanish, French, Italian, Portuguese), but English allows singular and plural for collective nouns.