# Plurals: Is it live or lives and Is it work or works in this example?

Tags: grammatical-number, british-english

Which is correct?

> The Maritime Quarter Residents' Association support and represent everyone that **live** and **work** in the Maritime Quarter.

or

> The Maritime Quarter Residents' Association support and represent everyone that **lives** and **works** in the Maritime Quarter.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. What do you think, and why do you distrust it? Please add your research!

Comment: FYI, _everyone_, despite what it means, is **singular**. _**Is** everyone here? Yes, everyone **is** here._

Comment: What about support(s) and represent(s)? Why am I think those should have S's?

Answer (score 4):

It's lives and works:

The Maritime Quarter Residents' Association support**s** and represent**s** everyone that live**s** and work**s** in the Maritime Quarter.

Everyone is singular.

I also changed 'supports' and 'represents' in reference to 'Association' which as pointed out in comments, depends mostly on whether you're speaking British or American English.

Comment: Not necessarily, and [not even necessarily by default](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1338/are-collective-nouns-always-plural-or-are-certain-ones-singular).

Comment: Oh that's interesting.. according to that link, "Association" would more often be treated as a plural noun in Britain, and singular in America.  It does sound more formal somehow to treat it as plural.

Comment: @RegDwigнt, elendee: Good to see the comment system working well there. I passed by this answer before even the *first* edit but didn't upvote -
 probably because I was niggled by the *supports and represents* bit. But if I'm honest, I'd never expect, say, *The Automobile Association **employ** thousands of patrolmen* (because of the associations of the word "association"! :) But I'm fine with [*The AA **provide** a more than adequate map suitable for tourists and trampers alike.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22the+AA+provide+a+more+than+adequate+map%22)

Comment: Opinions differ, obviously, but when *[the] **Association*** (capitalised or not) is used as an unqualified proper noun, I see it as being like *[the] [police] **force***. I can't imagine a police chief saying to his new recruits *We're an employee-friendly Police Force. Whatever support you need, **the Force are with you.*** On the other hand, I found [*The association **provide** emotional support and information to people with lymphatic cancer and to their families, carers and friends.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22The+association+provide+emotional+support+and%22)