# Should “megafauna” take a plural verb or a singular one?

Tags: grammatical-number, collective-nouns

I know *megafauna* is not a very common word, while *fauna* is more so. *Fauna* is singular, defined as a group of animals. ex. "The African fauna is diverse".

*Megafauna* is the word defining all animals with body mass larger than a certain threshold (45kg, 100kg, etc), so in theory is still a group.
Following this logic, megafauna should be singular.

However in many prominent scientific publications, for example some articles in *Science* and *Nature*, you find *megafauna* used in the plural form. ex. "Megafauna are a major draw for tourists" or "megafauna are imperiled".

Checking online some dictionaries define it as plural and singular. Are these scientists grammatically "wrong" by using megafauna as a plural noun, or are they simply setting the standard for how a word should be used since language evolves and they are the most expert on the subject?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they are not wrong. They are simply using [***collective nouns***](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/collective-nouns) in a way that you are unfamiliar with. This is called notional concord, or sometimes notional agreement. [This happens all the time in English.](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/notional-agreement-subject-verb-principle-proximity) That makes this question a stealth duplicate of [“Are collective nouns always plural, or are certain ones singular?”](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/1338/2085)

The [OED says of *megafauna*](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/245210?redirectedFrom=megafauna#eid) that it can take plural concord as a collective noun:

> 1. Chiefly *Palaeontology*. With *plural* concord: large vertebrates, esp. the larger mammals; spec. those of a particular epoch or region. Also (with *singular* concord): a group, class, community, or list of such animals. Cf. **microfauna** *n*. 1.
> 2. *Ecology*. = **macrofauna** *n*.

This is no surprise.

The word *fauna* is a collective noun, which means it **can** take plural verbs but does not require them. Here are examples from Google Books:

- Preliminary results suggest that the endemic spider fauna are confined to the intact natural forests in the south-west and the central highland region. 
  —[*The Fauna of Sri Lanka: Status of Taxonomy, Research, and Conservation*](https://books.google.com/books?id=KpSwBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA71&dq=%22fauna+are%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi_i9C_novdAhVr34MKHZNbDiYQ6AEIVDAI)
- The law further defines protected, controlled and common aquatic fauna in terms of the three-category classification system established in the law on Aquatic Animals and Wildlife: protected aquatic fauna are classified as Category I; controlled ... 
  —[*Review of statutory and customary law in the Xe Champhone Ramsar site*](https://books.google.com/books?id=IfXaktgSGE8C&pg=PA20&dq=%22fauna+are%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi_i9C_novdAhVr34MKHZNbDiYQ6AEIqwEwGA#v=onepage&q=%22fauna%20are%22&f=false)
- Sand fauna, silty-sand fauna, and silty-clay fauna are common to this zone. 
  —[*Ocean Dumping of Sludge in New York Bight: Environmental Impact Statement*](https://books.google.com/books?id=H-U0AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA102&dq=%22fauna+are%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi_i9C_novdAhVr34MKHZNbDiYQ6AEIugEwGw#v=onepage&q=%22fauna%20are%22&f=false)

This works just like uncountably many other collective nouns that are singular in form yet often plural in use: *group, team, community, couple, pair, council, club, company, troop, crowd, gang,* et cetera ad infinitum.

Comment: So are you saying that 'megafauna' is just like 'fauna' with respect to number, or are there differences?

Comment: @Mitch Yes, I am. I haven't found any differences.

Comment: Not happy with this. You can have prides of lions; the dictionaries classing 'megafauna' as an invariant plural mean that there can similarly be megafauna. cf 4 brace of pheasant (though arguably a compound numeral-substitute).

Answer (score 2):

Evidence from [Google Books](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=megafauna%20is%2C%20megafauna%20are&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmegafauna%20is%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmegafauna%20are%3B%2Cc0) suggests that the term “megafauna” has been used both both in the  singular and the  plural forms at least since the ‘60s

***[Megafauna](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/megafauna)***

> *n. pl. megafauna or megafaunas*:
>
> Large or relatively large animals of a particular region, period, or habitat: Pleistocene megafauna; crabs and other aquatic megafauna.

***[Megafauna:](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/megafauna)***

> (mass noun)
> The large mammals of a particular region, habitat, or geological period.

From [Mass Extinction](https://books.google.it/books?id=U4QfBzdJJ8EC&pg=PA162&dq=%22megafauna%20are%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiI3OjfnIvdAhUFjqQKHcpLB7oQ6AEIKTAB#v=onepage&q=%22megafauna%20are%22&f=false) :

> Some Australian researches maintain that ***megafauna are absent*** in Australian fossil sites dated younger than ~46 ka, the suggested date of colonization by humans.

From [Biodiversity](https://books.google.it/books?id=QI7K9axbKkQC&pg=PA147&dq=%22megafauna%20is%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiazYOEnYvdAhVCKuwKHTcVBRAQ6AEIPjAF#v=onepage&q=%22megafauna%20is%22&f=false):

> ***The megafauna is still well represented***, even if 50 varieties disappeared around 40 000 years ago. Africa is the continent that currently has the most diversified fauna of large herbivores, including the elephant, hippopotamus, rhinoceros, etc. – groups that were plentiful on other continents before the Pleistocene extinctions.

Comment: so fauna also exists as a plural? What would be its purpose if it already implies a group?

Comment: @Herman Toothrot Six prides of lions, three herds of sheep, 112 pairs of shoes, the German and British fleets, 4 brace of pheasants ....