# What is the correct Verb form?

Tags: verb-agreement

A group of women *seek* an appointment.
or
A group of women *seeks* an appointment.
Which is correct?

Comment: Is it the group seeking an appointment (i.e. seeking an appointment together) or is it each individual in the group seeking a separate appointment?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are collective nouns always plural, or are certain ones singular?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1338/are-collective-nouns-always-plural-or-are-certain-ones-singular)

Answer (score 2):

ETA: *Appointment* is singular, so we're going to assume that the group is seeking an appointment together, versus individually seeking separate appointments. In this case, a singular verb is best.

*A group of women seeks an appointment* is correct.

Comment: Thank you, @Chappo, I have edited the answer. I assume the system will unflag it?

Comment: An edit does reset some [review queues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161390), but I'm not sure about the Low Quality Queue, since most posts in the LQQ are flagged by a system algorithm that looks not only at *length* but also *content* (e.g. whether there's a link to supporting evidence). I think you've still missed the key point, that the *subject* ("a group") is singular: the number of appointments the group is seeking is a red herring. Nonetheless, I've reversed my downvote in recognition of your effort to improve your answer. :-)

Comment: Welcome to ELU, Annie. As a Brit, I'd use notional agreement. Certainly 'Local Women's Group seeks new place to meet'. But 'a group of women' sounds far less unitary, and I'd go with 'a group of women / a dozen women seek an appointment' (they all want an appointment, but they want to attend the same one), where 'a group of' corresponds to a quantifier rather than a traditional collective noun. Cf 'the staff are seeking an appointment'.