# Is it to be wish or wishes?

Tags: grammar

Am I to use wish or wishes in the following sentence?

As we are into a New Year, XYZ Co. wish you happy, success and safety in 2020!

Comment: By the way, that should be 'happiness', not 'happy'. Or 'a happy, successful and safe 2020'.

Comment: I also suspect you want 2021.

Comment: Also, New Year should not be capitalized and the use of *into* is non-standard.  Maybe you want “As we enter into a new year” or “As we usher in a new year”

Comment: _Wish_ in _I wish you_ is a verb. You can send someone your _best wishes_.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are collective nouns always plural, or are certain ones singular?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1338/are-collective-nouns-always-plural-or-are-certain-ones-singular)